# How to use ng-switch as a router for my pages with ngRoute & ngView?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Here is the highlevel skeleton of my Angular SPA. My application is about college degree offerings. In that engineering page has a separate left nav which is currently built on ng-switch which i want to convert as route. How do i do that just using angular's native routing angular-route.js?

```
**app.js**
(function(){
   var app=angular.module("myCollege",['ngRoute']);

   app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',  
          function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider 

                 .when('/', {
                       templateUrl:"app/views/home.html",
                       controller:"homeController",
                       }

                    .when('/engg', {
                       templateUrl:"app/views/engineering.html",
                       controller:"engineeringController",
                       })
                    .when('/med', {
                       templateUrl:"app/views/medical.html",
                       controller:"medicalController",
                       })

                  }]);
```

> I have left nav in engineering.html using ng-switch which i want to
>   convert as sub-route of the application.This left nav of engineering
>   page is not inside of ngView. How do i acheive this using angular's
>   native ngRoute/angular-route?

```
**engineering.html**

<div nav ng-switch on="pagename()">
        <div ng-switch-when="Civil Engineering">
               <div civil-directive> </div>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Computer Engineering">
               <div computer-directive> </div>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Nano Engineering">
               <div nano-directive> </div>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Electrical Engineering">
               <div electrical-directive> </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

**EngineeringController.js**

```
(function() {
var app =angular.module("collegeApp");
var engineeringController= functino($scope,$rootscope,$location)

 {

   $scope.pagename = function() {
      return $location.path();
   };
app.controller("engineeringController",['$scope','$rootScope','$location',engineeringController])
}());
```

The above logic is not working for me. Can someone tell me where i am doing the wrong?

Comment: is engineering.html supposed to be a navigation bar?

Comment: yes.it is a navbar

Comment: @thegio i have updated my question with controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good practice but here's what you want to do if you want to use ng-switch:

In your **html**, as you write for example:

```
<!-- don't forget to reference your app and your controller -->
<button ng-click="goTo('/page1')">Go to page 1</button>
<button ng-click="goTo('/page2')">Go to page 2</button>
<div nav ng-switch on="pagename()">
     <div ng-switch-when="'/page1'"></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="'/page2'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-view> </div>
```

in **js**

```
Config your routes
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/page1', {
                templateUrl: 'views/page1.html'
            }).
            when('/page2', {
                templateUrl: 'views/page2.html'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }])
```

and add the following in your controller:

```
$scope.pagename = function() { return $location.path(); };

    $scope.goTo = function(page){
        $location.path(page);
    }
```

In the html above, ng-switch will use the $location.path() variable to know which view to display.

As I said this is not a good practice, because your controller isn't suppose to deal with routes.

Comment: I want my URL(after hash tag ) needs to be changed as per user selection. will your approach fulfill my requirement?

Comment: I've update my answer. Also, I've done an example of it in a server of mine in order to show you that url changes and everything working.
http://artyoni.net/test/index.html#/
Please let me know that you've checked it, because I won't let this code into my server for a long time