# How can I send a message from one controller to another in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following set up:

```js
stApp.controller('AdminTableController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'gridService', 
            function ($rootScope, $scope, gridService) {
    $scope.$watch('tableData.$pristine', function (newValue) {
        $rootScope.broadcast("tableDataUpdated", {
            state: page.$pristine
        });
    });
}])

stApp.controller('AdminGridController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'gridService',
            function ($rootScope, $scope, gridService) {
    $rootScope.on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
        //args.state would have the state.
        alert(args.state);
    });
}])
```

When I run this code I am getting a message:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
```

Note that I tried this with both $rootScope.on and $scope.on

Comment: Actually, you need to use ´$on´ instead of ´on´ and $broadcast instead of broadcast

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must have meant `$broadcast` and `$on` (rather than `broadcast` and `on`), that is:

```js
$rootScope.$broadcast("tableDataUpdated", { state: page.$pristine });
// ...
$rootScope.$on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
// ...
```

It's worth noting that `$broadcast` is used to delegate events to child or sibling scopes, whereas `$emit` will bubble events upwards to the scope's parents, hence;

When choosing `$broadcast` (and not `$emit`), one should either inject the root scope for tying the `$on` (as you nicely *did*) or call `$on` on the receiver's isolated scope, be it a child scope of the dispatcher.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/547020) for elaboration on `$emit` and `$broadcast`.

Answer (score 7):

If the event listener is in a **child scope**: `$scope.$broadcast('MyEvent', args);`

If the event listener is in a **parent scope**: `$scope.$emit('MyEvent', args);`

You could avoid any confusion by using $broadcast on $rootScope, since $rootScope is the parent of all scopes in an Angular application: `$rootScope.$broadcast('MyEvent', args);`

Whether you use $emit or $broadcast, the receiving controller listens with `$scope.$on('MyEvent', function() {});`

Comment: I think it is the other way around. $emit sends upwards from child scope to parent scope. $broadcast goes from parent to child. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I wrote listener instead of emitter, but I've fixed it here so they're reversed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
 $rootScope.on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
        //args.state would have the state.
        alert(args.state);
    });
```

should be

```
 $rootScope.$on("tableDataUpdated", function (args) {
        //args.state would have the state.
        alert(args.state);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$emit('MyEvent', args);
```

from first controller, and receive in second controller:

```
$scope.$on('MyEvent', function() {});
```