# AngularJS: pass messages to a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a question about style, or *the angular way*.

When a user signs up, I *send them a confirmation email* and *redirect to `'/'`*.

Also, when logging in, if the user hasn't confirmed their email, I give them an option to resend the confirmation email. I *resend the confirmation email* and *redirect to `'/'`*.

In both cases I would like to **display an informational message** at the top of the home page.

I have found a way to do this.

I create some dummy routes which have a `blank template` and a simple `controller` which sets a message on a `service` and redirects to `'/'`:

It just feels a little hackish. Having to specify a non-empty `template` is particularly ugly.

I'm sure there *must be a better way to do this?* To some how pass `$scope` to a controller upon redirection, or something along those lines.

**Here is my implementation**

*Dummy routes:*

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/confirm', {
            template: " ",
            controller: function(Message, $location) {
                Message.info = "We've sent you a confirmation email - please check your inbox";
                $location.path('/');
            }
        })
        .when('/reconfirm', {
            template: " ",
            controller: function(Message, $location) {
                Message.info = "We've resent your confirmation email - please check your inbox";
                $location.path('/');
            }
        })
```

*Message service:*

```
app.factory('Message', function () {
    this.message = {
        info: "",
    };
    return this.message;
});
```

For completeness, here is the message **partial** and **controller**

*Partial* (pulled into `index.html` with `ng-include`):

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MessageCtrl">
        <div ng-show="message.info" class="alert alert-info">
            {{ message.info }}
            <button class="close pull-right" ng-click="message.info=''">&times;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Controller*:

```
app.controller('MessageCtrl', function($scope, Message) {
    $scope.message = Message;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $emit / $on to do that.

You can use the MessageCtrl to display a message that trigger on an event using $on

```
$scope.$on('EventName', function(event, anyInput) {
    // Do your magic
}
```

From the other controllers sending the message you do an $emit. You can use $rootScope to make it global if you want to too.

```
$scope.$emit('EventName', inputToThe$on);
```

Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wHgh/

Here is another good explanation of $emit and $broadcast: [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs)

Hope it is a useful alternative.

Comment: This is a neat option!