# nested controllers in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

we're pretty new to this. After finally managing to get ui-Bootstrap working with a date control :-

```
<div class="col-md-2 box" ng-controller="ResultFilter" >  
<h2>Filter</h2>

    <p class="input-group" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="resultfilter.startdate" is-open="opened1" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'opened1')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </p>
   <p class="input-group" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="resultfilter.enddate" is-open="opened2" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event, 'opened2')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </p>
 <p class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="resultfilter.frequency">
  <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
<option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
<option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
<option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
</select>
      </p>
</div>
```

We are capturing the click with the following angular

```
CISApp.controller('ResultFilter', function ResultFilter($scope, $http) {
$scope.updateResults = function () {

 };
});
```

how ever, how do we get at value of start date as it is within the controller of DatePickerDemoCtrl?
The following doesnt work?

```
$scope.resultfilter.startdate
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: As an addition to Khanh TO's answer, check out this excellent thread that explains javascript & angular's inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-controller` creates new scope. Both of your `DatepickerDemoCtrl` are child scopes of `ResultFilter`. In your case, You could try:

```
$scope.$$childHead.resultfilter.startdate
```

This solution is not recommended IMO as it creates **tightly coupled code**, you're assuming that there is a child scope for this controller, some more recommended approaches:

- Use [$on, $emit, $broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs) to communicate between scopes.
- Create a shared service to hold the state (I think does not apply in your case)

Comment: works brilliant, will take a look at the other approaches that you suggested, how ever, not reached any of those methods yet in my training book

Comment: @Simon: You should take a look as they create a better code.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs It will help you understand much better scopes and inheritance.