# emit event from scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am confused about the emit event in scope.

For example the structure.

```
<scope00></scope00>
<scope0>
<scope1>
  <scope2>
    <scope3>
       <scope4></scope4>
    </scope3>
    <scope4>

    </scope4>
  </scope2>
</scope1>
</scope0>
```

So my question is,

$scope2.$emit("myevent", data);

What are the scopes can capture this "myevent"?

and what would be the difference between $scope0.$emit and $scope2.$emit.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit)

> emit-Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying
> the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners

So scope1 and scope0 can capture 'myevent' if emitted from scope2...

Also give this answer a read [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs/14502755#14502755)

Comment: Is that possible to capture by their upward sibling scope and childscope?

Comment: sorry for the late reply...no it shouldn't be captured by its upward sibling scope...

Comment: $scope2.$broadcast("myevent", data); In this case, what the elements can capture the event.? Hope rootscope can't capture.