# AngularJs - why is $emit not working from my popup window

Tags: angularjs, emit

I'm using the bootstrap popup modal window, and trying to $emit and event but for some reason the main page is not detecting the event.  It's a pretty simple setup, but I can't figure out why.  From what I can tell when viewing Batarang it appears the popup is a child scope of the main app scope so I thought it would work but it doesn't.  In this simple app when you press 'ok' in the popup window it should set a value in the parent scope.  Here's a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/F2W1LaWSsqinaFpiISAr?p=preview

```
//Here's code where $emit is called in the child (Factory):
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'popupMyWindow.html',
                pScope: parentScope,
                controller: 
                    function($scope, $modalInstance){
                        $scope.ok = function () {
                            $scope.$emit('ModalSelect', 'hello world');
                            $modalInstance.close(null);
                        }
                    },

//Here's where $on is called in the main controller:
 $scope.$on('ModalSelect', function (event, selected) {
            console.log('ModalSelect called successfully');
            $scope.selectedValue = selected;
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to pass `$scope` to a Service. `$scope` is very contextual to where it is placed in the View, so can you really know whether you should `$emit` or `$broadcast`? Also, it's more difficult to unit-test when you pass `$scope`. Instead, pass a callback function.

That being said, you are calling `$emit` on a `$modal` directive's scope, which may be an isolated scope (I don't know how that directive is defined) so it never reaches the parent.

So you can either do:

```
parentScope.$emit('ModalSelect', 'hello world');
```

Or, you can use `$rootScope`:

```
$scope.$root.$broadcast('ModalSelect', 'hello world');
```

Comment: However this is bad practice. For one, performance: root will $emit to all child scopes in your app whether they are listening or not. Secondly you create a dependency to the rootScope thus reducing reusability (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)

Comment: To be precise, `$emit` bubbles up the hierarchical chain, and `$broadcast` - down. So, root will `$emit` only to `$rootScope.$on` listeners. But even with `$broadcast` - the performance problem was fixed - [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19498009/968155) - and only actual listeners will be notified.