# how to $watch a change on service value without using the services scope angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

So I have a controller watching for changes from several different services that are injected into it. The controller is currently inheriting each of the service's scope to $watch one value from it. I would love to find a way to $watch that one value without dragging the services entire scope into the mix. Here is my psuedo code for it:

```
function controller {
    $scope.$watch(myService.value, function(newVal) {
        $scope.value = newVal;
    });

}
```

Any pointers on how to avoid using the services scope to update the controller would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: May be `function controller($scope, mySvc){}`?

Comment: That's not even valid code for an angular controller. Question isn't clear and it doesn't help when code is invalid and doesn't show much. WHat does `dragging service scope into it` even mean?

Comment: like i said its pseudo code, rough idea of what I have. right now the $watch is bringing in the entire scope of the service. How could I work it so I am not reading from the services scope in the controller?

Comment: Have look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/how-to-watch-service-variables

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pretty cool feature of Angular. Angularjs comes with a built in messaging system for communicating between modules/sevices/factories etc.

In your service you could use

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('value:changed', { value: newValue });
```

and in your controller you can catch the change like so:

```
$scope.$on('value:changed', function(message) {
   $scope.value = message.newValue;

});
```

Of course, to use this approach you need a way to know when that value will change so you can broadcast it to the controller.

Hoped this helped!
Let me know!

**Cheers**

*For more info on $broadcast (and/or $emit) here's a ref:* [Why do we use $rootScope.$broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)
Official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope