# How to access another scope with controller?

Tags: angularjs

I know that you can create binding with a directive but is it possible with a controller? Maybe this is stupidly simple but I couldn't figure out.

For example I would like to click on a text in x scope's view and execute a function in another scope.

```
function firstCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = 'First scope stuff!';
}

function secondCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = 'Second scope stuff!';
  }

  vm.clicked = function() {
    alert('firstScope is clicked!'); 
  };
```

Here is what I have: http://plnkr.co/edit/CpPKsEGPZWzufB2K1FK3

Comment: Check out using `$.broadcast` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs

Comment: Is there a reason that the function can't be in a service instead of the controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs

Comment: @Mar possibility that „technical design” is wrong.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski maybe.. I would like to know the answer though. But I have just read the answer of the questions 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs' and that explains to me.

Comment: @Mar – so, first you asked than looked for answer?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski I asked because I couldn't find it

Comment: what u want in your plunk is just impossible -- if I click on first href - second controller is not initialized, so ofc I cant use his methods.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways how to communicate between controllers.
One way is emitting an event on scope:

```js
function FirstCtrl($scope) 
{
  $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, args) {});
  // another controller or even directive
}

function SecondCtrl($scope) 
{
  $scope.$emit('someEvent', args);
}
```

Another way sharing a service.

Hope it helps. Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407953/4782034

Comment: $emit is rare case to use it, if controller hierarchy is there