# $rootScope.$broadcast not picked up in ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, broadcast

I'm using ui-router to display 2 ui-views, one within the other.  They are organized like this:

```
.state('itemAbstract', {
    url: '/items',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'client/views/item.ng.html',
    controller: 'moveCtrl',
})
.state('item', {
    url: "/:itemId",
    parent: "itemsAbstract",
    views: {
        "otherpage":{
            templateUrl: 'client/views/other-page.ng.html',
            controller: 'otherPageCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

I run the folloowwing in the `otherpage` controller when an item is clicked.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("somethingClicked",obj)
```

I try to listen for the event in the `item` controller:

```
$scope.$on("somethingClicked",function(a,b){
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b);
})
```

Unfortunately, this function never gets called.  I tried putting this listener function in the `otherpage` controller, and it was called correctly when the event happened.  For some reason, though, this broadcast isn't getting transferred across scopes. That was the whole reason I was using this, to trigger an action in the parent when something in the parent is clicked.  Any ideas on why this is not working?

Here is my controller for the item

```
angular.module('mm').controller('itemCtrl',
function($scope, $meteor, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    var s = $scope;
    s.rs = $rootScope;

    $scope.$on("somethingClicked",function(a,b){
        console.log("there as a click")
        console.log(a)
        console.log(b);
    })
}
```

I used Batarang to debug and found that despite this code, $scope *is not even registering an event listener*.  `$scope.$$listeners` does *not* have a listener for the somethingClicked event.  Very strange, and it doesn't make sense why this isn't working.

Comment: your on listens on $scope and you are broadcasting on $rootScope. may i know why is it so ?

Comment: I was hoping that if I listen with just $scope, then the listener will be destroyed when the $scope is destroyed on page change.  I don't want a ghost listener hanging on to $rootscope after the page has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have independent controllers with no inheritance applied. Inheritance on $scope is declared simply by nesting the controllers on your view. In that case you may use $rootscope to broadcast or listen to event as:

```
//ctrl1    
$rootScope.$broadcast("somethingClicked",obj);

//ctrl2

$rootScope.$on("somethingClicked",function(a,b){
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b);
});
```

Take a look at this simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8bsxxvj/) as well as an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs) on Stack Overflow.

**EDITED**
Based on your sample code I had no problem at all communicating using `$rootscope`.

The state declaration use an abstract parent controller and a fetched child controller mapped into the view as:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('test', {

          url: '/test',
          controller: 'pctrl',
          views: {
            'main': {
              template: '<div ng-controller="pctrl">{{test}}</div>' +
                '<div ui-view="childview"></div>'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('test.child', {
          url: '/test/child',
          controller: 'cctrl',
          views: {
            'childview': {
              template: '<div ng-controller="cctrl" />'
            }
          }
        });
```

Here is a **[full working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8bsxxvj/)**

Comment: I tried that already!  Unfortunately it does not work. I'm injecting $rootScope into the controller, yet still nothing!  I'm thinking this has something to do with my implementation of ui-router

Comment: It's so complicated... If I can't figure it out I'll try to put something up.  Strangely, this code: https://coderwall.com/p/h72qlg/10-lines-of-js-to-log-all-emit-events-in-angularjs does not indicate that an event has been fired when I run it.

Comment: OK stripped down my controller and actual controller code to my question!

Answer (score 0):

Answer found - I had misconfigured my routes file, and had the wrong controller specified for the page I was loading.  That's why none of my event listeners registered!