# Angular - Change scope variable across multiple directive instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive project. Multiple projects are set on a page. Based on a data attribute it sets a scope variable to true or false. I want to be able to set all scope variables to false.

I can provide code if necessary but essentially my question is how can I click on a button to affect the scope variable in every single instance of a directive on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `$rootScope.$broadcast`and a `$scope.$on`, that acts like an event dispatching and listening system. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609612/3399432) for more details on how to implement this.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution, since it made more sense in the context of my project. For those wondering I had a directive with multiple instances on the page. A rootscope broadcast notified all of them to react accordingly. Using $watch in a service felt like reinventing the wheel, where as this worked with very little code.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, I would create a service where that data would live. On each directive, I would $watch that service and update the variables when it changes.

Comment: I think a small change would work a little better, since the OP seems to already have the directive changing value in one controller, change that controller to get/set the value within the service then all other controllers that know about that service will get the update.