# Why isn't my Angular event handler called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling

In one controller of my Angular 1.4.7 app I fire an event like so:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth:login-finished');
```

then in another controller, I attempt to listen to this event with

```
$scope.$on('event:auth:login-finished', function () {
  console.debug('ROOT AUTH HANDLER CALLED');
});
```

For some reason, the handler is never called, even though the event is definitely being fired, am I doing something wrong?

### Update

I've also tried listening to the root scope

```
$rootScope.$on('event:auth:login-finished', function () {
  console.debug('ROOT AUTH HANDLER CALLED');
});
```

But this doesn't get called either

Comment: Another common problem is that your controller gets instantiated after the event is broadcast.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about when the event is fired?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcast not received in directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882975/broadcast-not-received-in-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$rootScope.$on` to catch it.

The key is to get the "root".

Comment: I would need to see more code to accurately diagnose the problem. $rootScope.$on should be defined before you trigger it (i.e. the location of this code should be before the call). You can also try $rootScope.$emit or $scope.$emit instead of $rootScope.$broadcast if you're trying to restrict scope.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationship between the controllers.  Calling $broadcast will fire the event to all child scopes.  So if the $on is not in a child controller, then it won't fire.

Putting the $on on the rootScope should work.

```
$rootScope.$on('event:auth:login-finished', function () {
  console.debug('ROOT AUTH HANDLER CALLED');
});
```