# $rootScope.$broadcast not getting triggered

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code :

Test.html:

```
<div>Test</div>
<dta-feed my-list="myList"></dta-feed>
```

TestCtrl.js

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $scope.loadData();                
 });

 $scope.loadData = function () {
  $rootScope.$broadcast("testEvent");               
 }
```

dtafeed-directive.js

```
$scope.$on("testEvent", function () {
  console.log('Testing broadcast event');           
});
```

Can anyone help me to know h

Comment: I will need more context. Can you show us your application configuration? like when or how your directive is being added to the application and when and how the controller is added as well

Comment: Is your directive ready when you broadcast?

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for your response. It is a good question raised by you. But can you please help me to know how to check whether directtive is ready in this case.

Comment: You can debug or log the sequence in which they are instantiated. 1 at the broadcast on the root, 2 in the directive (link lifecycle hook perhaps, can't rembember)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try?

Test.html :

```
<div>Test</div>
<dta-feed my-list="myList"></dta-feed>
```

TestCtrl.js

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  $scope.loadData();                
 });

 $scope.loadData = function () {
  $rootScope.$broadcast("testEvent");               
 }
```

dtafeed-directive.js

```
var ev = $rootScope.$on("testEvent", function () {
  console.log('Testing broadcast event');           
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    ev();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me to fix the issue 
[Broadcast not received in directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882975/broadcast-not-received-in-directive)

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$broadcast('testEvent');
});
```