# Angular Js data sharing between controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have two parallel controllers headerCtrl and cartCtrl . when I add a product from cartCtrl I want to reflect the count increase in headerCtrl . What is the best way to achieve this ?

I know Using shared services we can achieve this : when a product got added update the count in service . but how can I update the count in headerCtrl ?

Also if there is any other best approach to achieve this ?

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between controllers in Angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181323/passing-data-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: you can use Service to pass data between controller or can also use rootScope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I'd use service to share data between controllers. So you create a service like below and access/modify it from both controllers. To notify other components, you can use $rootScope.$emit to pass the data. This is usually more efficient than $broadcast if you don't need to propagate event to all child scopes. This is a quick way to do it - however you may quickly end up in a situation where every component depends on $rootScope, an alternative is set up listeners through a service: [Why do we use $rootScope.$broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)

```
angular.module('app').service('myService', function($rootScope) {
 var count = 0;

 this.increaseCount = function() {
     count++;
     $rootScope.$emit('countUpdated', count);
 }

 this.getCount = function () {
     return count;
 }
});

angular.module('app').controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('countUpdated', function(count) {
    // do your stuff
  });
}])
```

Comment: How can I call the getCount() from the HeaderCtrl ? Do I need to refresh it ?

Comment: yes i can inject it and call the myService.getCount() . But I need to call this function in headerCtrl when a product got added in cartCtrl . So How will I trigger the call ?

Comment: emit will work in case of parallel controller as it will emit to the parent controller only I think?

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer - if you $emit the event on $rootScope, you can catch it by adding a listener on $rootScope. This is usually better than $broadcast if you don't need to propagate event to all child scopes

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are two issues to be tackled here
1. One is share of data : this can be achieved by having a service
2. Another is automatic update at destination controller i.e without calling get. For this use angular [broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Broadcast will work with parallel controller as I think broadcast fire the event to the child controller only ?

Comment: Im guessing it should not matter. Broadcast is a way of pub-sub in angular