# Angular - async updates & rendering from service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, rendering

I have a `Service` that listens to webSockets (can't use callbacks or promises, data updates are random). service gets updates and saves them to service's object. I Have an angular-app page with controller that has the service object in the `$scope`.

But I got a problem in rendering data on the page. Right now I am using $timeout() to update the view but looking for a more elegant way.

I understand that I can use `$watch` on the service's object, but I think that it is too heavy for browser.

So what is the right way to render the view/controller after changes in service's data?

Comment: you can also use $scope.$apply() but ultimatly going to call watch only..

Comment: There's not enough information. To optimize things `$scope.$digest()` may be used. It triggers a digest on current scope and nested ones, while any other way triggers a digest on root scope.

Comment: Sounds interesting! But for calling $digest I need the $scope...?
Any way, here is some simple example of my problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/53m5cOe8XDDDRrxFX0NK?p=preview

Tried to simulate comming webSockets data with "setTimeout()". I can't work with promises because data pushed.. 

In service.js you have commented $timeout - if you will uncomment it render will start to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` as an alternative but it's also as heavy as $watch, I don't know why you are afraid of using $watch, the cost in performance is not that big !!

To use `$broadcast` add this line of code to your service :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('WatchedData', data);
```

And in your controller do something like the following :

```
$scope.$on('WatchedData', function(event) {  return stuff  });
```

to read more about `$rootscope.$broadcast` check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs)** SO answer

Comment: I guess broadcast is 'cheaper' than `$watch` because it uses an already-existing listener to `$rootScope`. Am I guessing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use **resolve** , it will load data before controller and View is instantianting in your routing file , and inject your Service into function

You can watch this Demo  [PLunker Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/kHXK54)

Comment: Data pushed after the page is ready and  every few seconds coming packs with updates.