# AngularJS Calling function in controller after data is loaded in another file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function in app.js which connects to an api using promises. The app that is selected to be opened depends on the user ID.

```
me.boot = function () {
me.getUserID().then(me.openAppFunction);
};
```

Also, I have this function in my Home.js controller

```
getObjectsFromApp();
```

This function needs to be executed after the application is loaded in the other file, but I have no idea how to do this. This app.js file is not a service or a factory, it is just a file that is called when the application loads all the scripts with require.js. The only thing this file does is select which app to open in the api, so that is why it is only called once.

Comment: So, you would like to execute getObjectsFromApp function in Home controller when the promise for getUserId is resolved? Is that right?

Comment: Yes @pedromarce, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

An `Event` is probably what you are looking for...

You should stay in the angular environment, so, you should use `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$on` and they can be used everywhere in your application because `$rootScope` is singletone.

this [Why do we use $rootScope.$broadcast in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs) could help you.

Comment: @Alexander Frass Your other function in the other script file is not in an angular script right ?