# passing data to another controller using $rootScope.$broadcast

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

its like signup menu first controller gets the data from the user and after the validation 
it sends the data to $rootScope and broadcast it so the
second controller can get it and show the data in myInfo tab

don't know whats wrong but the second controller cant get the data

### first controller

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module("public").controller("SignUpController", SignUpController);
      SignUpController.$inject = ["$rootScope"];
      function SignUpController($rootScope) {
        let signUpCtrl = this;
        signUpCtrl.name = "";
        signUpCtrl.email = "";

        signUpCtrl.submit = () => {

          signUpCtrl.formSbmitted = true;

          $rootScope.$broadcast("user:created", {
            name: signUpCtrl.name,
            email: signUpCtrl.email
          });
        };
      }
})();
```

### second controller

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module("public").controller("MyInfoController", MyInfoController);
      MyInfoController.$inject = ["$rootScope"];
      function MyInfoController($rootScope) {
        let myInfo = this;

        $rootScope.$on("user:created", function(event, data) {
          myInfo.data = data;
        });
      }
})();
```

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830679/why-do-we-use-rootscope-broadcast-in-angularjs). Do NOT use $rootScope.$on use $scope.$on! Also you may need to call $rootScope.$broadcast.$apply.

Comment: @Mickers In the context of this question, `$rootScope.$broadcast.$apply` is not needed and will in fact cause an error. Good catch with `$rootScope.$on`. It has potential for memory leaks.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/3PspJpvSygv12f0XJFCJ?p=preview).

Comment: yes it works when both controllers are in same view but when i use ui-router and everyone of then becomes responsible for different view it doesn't work as if the second controller is not instantiated yet