# How to pass data between non compiled and compiled nested directives in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dilemma, I have the following..

AppController
Directive1:  fruitfinder
Directive2 (may be multiplied):   detailsfound

A user does the following:
1. click a button handled by AppController that emits an event to show fruitfinder/directive1 which makes an ajax request to request a list of fruits.
A general "details found" directive is appended/compiled that needs to access a list of fruits that precounts up properties (i.e. color) ~this happens once fruitfinder/directive1 catches the emit event in the link function.

I tried to create an attribute in the "append" of the detailsfound directive and append the list (result from ajax) as a property on the detailsfound element but fails as there are spaces in the list and maybe characters html doesnt like in its properties..

What is an ideal way to pass information from my directive 1 to directive 2s? any suggestions on how to improve on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angulars `$broadcast` and `$on` functionality to transmit your data to the second directive.

How to exactly implement the broadcast feature depends on the relation between your controllers. You can use this SO-answer as help: [$scope.$emit and .$on angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/3346612)

Comment: How do you properly "kill" appended html/directive element in linl function?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand the relation to your question... What do you mean with 'linl function'?