# "ui-sref" does not refresh the "ui-view"(its controller does not rerun) when a link is clicked twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

When a state is clicked at first, the div that owns the "ui-view" attribute is replaced with the "template" of that state. However, when I click the same state again, its controller does not reloaded. How can I make this controller to load again?

For example, suppose I have the following navigation menu:

```
<nav> 
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</nav>
```

My "ui-view" content is as follows:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

My states are described as below. When I click the "State1" on the navigation menu, I expect to observe the text `"Ctrl 1 loaded"` on the `developer console`. If it's first time, then I observe that text. However, when I re-click the same link, the controller is not loaded again that is I couldn't see the text `"Ctrl 1 loaded"` displayed on the console twice.

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 1</p>",
        controller: "Ctrl1"
      }).state("state2", {
        url: "#",
        template: "<p>State 2</p>",
        controller: "Ctrl2"
      });
});
```

Why? Do you have any idea?

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/789Ks/1/) of this question.

Answer (score 86):

Like Philipp said, it is because this is the default behavior of ui-router, BUT if you would like to reload your controller each time you click on your link, you can actually use the **ui-sref-opts** attribute to force it, like this:

```
<a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">State 1</a>
```

Found this tip here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/91a568454cc600aa4f34dedc8a80c9be1130b1c5

Hope it could help

Comment: How can I do this throughout my application?

Comment: ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" also does not work for me and it did not reload the controller.

Comment: Only v0.2.5 later versions support the reload function
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#options

Answer (score 14):

Alternative syntax to go to a different view it would be

```
<a ui-sref="state1({reload: true})">State 1</a>
```

On the controller it would look like this.

```
$state.go('state1', {}, {reload: true});
```

Note: The second parameter of $state.go is $stateParams.

Comment: How random, for me its the other way around, `ui-sref-opts` works but passing `reload: true` into the state in `ui-sref` doesn't! Anyone else with this problem I recommend trying either.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how ui-router is designed.

The controller is only loaded when it isn't in the same state. ui-router will not rerun a controller, and not reevaluate a view template.
Even when you use the same controller on multiple states and switch between those, the controller will not rerun.

If you want to run functionality when the a view changes you could [listen for events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events), or even put an `ng-click` on your `a` element.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can call the function again with ng-click ?

Comment: @ankakusu You'd probably have to set up a listener in the controller and emit an event from the `ng-click`, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs).

Comment: ng-click event is supressed as well. I binded an ng-click event to State 1. Even though I click on the item, ng-click event is not fired. You can check from [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/ya/pen/Kantr?editors=101).

Comment: @ankakusu `Ctrl1` controls only the elements below `ui-view`, `click` defined on the scope of `Ctrl1` will only get triggered if you call if from within the view. [Here's a sample with a navbar controller](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/awGJL). If you use this, with messaging on the scope with `$emit` ( on click ) and `$on` ( in the `Ctrl1` ), you can receive the event, on `Ctrl1`'s scope.

Comment: <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ng-click="createNewHome()">Create New Home</a>                                           
 it's not working properly. Please suggest me, what should we can change it...

Answer (score 1):

just use below code

```
$stateProvider.
  state('myPage', {
    url: '/',
    cache: false // add this line
```