# Controller wont refresh when ui-sref state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers, angular-ui-router, states

**Preface**

Clicking a ui-sref links wont refresh named views' controller.

### **Question**

How can I refresh the `WeeklyCtrl` When clicking on a `ui-sref="root.store.page.ad({ adSlug: promo.code })"` from `SidePanelCtrl`

*note there is a reload on the page. I see the favicon blink but no re-init of any controllers*
**routes.js**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.store', {
    url: ':storeSlug',
    views: {          
      'sidepanel': {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/side-panel.html',
        controller: 'SidePanelCtrl'
      },
      'weekly': {
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/weekly.html',
        controller: 'WeeklyCtrl'
      },
    }
  })
  .state('root.store.page', {

    url: '/page',

  })
  .state('root.store.page.ad', {
    url: '/:adSlug',


  })
```

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

**main.html**

```
  <div ui-view="weekly"></div>
  <div ui-view="sidepanel"></div>
```

**side-panel.html**

```
<a ng-repeat="promo in promos" ui-sref="root.store.page.ad({ adSlug: promo.code })"  >
    <h3>...</h3>
</a>
```

When `WeeklyCtrl` init it triggers an api call to will trigger.

```
Pages.details.getPages($scope).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

In the end I want this to trigger again when I switch between promos

**UPDATE:**

On click of a link:
API responds 3 times.  controller reinits multiple times
[image: 3 times]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's default behaviour. If you want to actually refresh the controller too, add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.boom = function(promoCode){
      $state.transitionTo("root.store.page.ad", 
          { adSlug: promoCode }, { notify: true }); 
};
```

and in your view:

```
<a ng-repeat="promo in promos" 
    ng-click="boom(promo.code);$event.preventDefault();"  >
    <h3>...</h3>
</a>
```

If you don't like this, feel free to download the source code of ui-sref and create new directive based on that, called **ui-sref-ctrl**

> That's how ui-router is designed.
>
> The controller is only loaded when it isn't in the same state.
>   ui-router will not rerun a controller, and not reevaluate a view
>   template. **Even when you use the same controller on multiple states and
>   switch between those, the controller will not rerun**.

["ui-sref" does not refresh the "ui-view"(its controller does not rerun) when a link is clicked twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155624/ui-sref-does-not-refresh-the-ui-viewits-controller-does-not-rerun-when-a-l)

Comment: Hey would you know based on my routes why the controller is getting refreshed 3 times?  image update above.

Comment: hm haven't had issue like that. Use chrome debugger and put breakpoint on controller initialization and look what happens on the call stack(eg who generates these initializations).