# How do I add markers to a Google Map?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to have an input field that when submitted adds a marker to my Google Map.  Right now when I submit the field it is creating the object but the marker is not being displayed.  Right now I am able to get a location to show up if it is hard coded in but not when I add a new one. (I know that the view right now is only for the hard coded one, I have that so the current code is working)

Here is my code:

My View:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" class="" ng-model="marker.markerLat" required="">
  <input type="number" class="" ng-model="marker.markerLng" required="">
  <button class="button" ng-click="addMarker(marker)">Add</button>
</form>
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
 <marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" idkey="marker.id" >
 </marker>
</google-map>
```

My Controller:

```
//Default location
        $scope.map = {
          center: {
            latitude: 32.7833,
            longitude: -79.9333
          },
          zoom: 11
        }
        $scope.options = {scrollwheel: true};

        $scope.markers = [];

        $scope.addMarker = function (marker) {

            $scope.markers.push({
                latitude: parseFloat($scope.markerLat),
                longitude: parseFloat($scope.markerLng)
            });

            console.log('Maker add: ' + $scope.markers);
            $scope.markerLat ="";
            $scope.markerLng ="";
        };

        $scope.marker = {
          id:0,
          coords: {
            latitude: 32.7833,
            longitude: -79.9333
          }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to create a custom angular directive for your map.

But anyway, angular is not enough to get what you want working. You have to create `google.maps` objects. And set the `map property` of your `marker` to the `map` you have created.

Here is a little example :

```
.directive('map', function () {
return {
  template: '<div></div>',
  restrict: 'EA',
  replace: true,
  link: function (scope, element) {

    scope.markers = [];

    scope.map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.7833, -79.9333),
      zoom: 11
    });

    scope.addMarker = function (lat, lnt) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: scope.map,
        position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
      });

      scope.markers.push(marker);
    };

  }
});
```

So you simply have to call the `addMarker` function with a `lat` and `lng` parameter. Use angular events to communicate between your controller and directive. More info about the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/scope-emit-and-on-angularjs)

Comment: Glad to have helped ! :)