# How to chain nested directives which use isolated scopes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to chain two nested directives that both use isolated scopes.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-dir on-done="done()">
        <my-dir2 on-done="done()">
        </my-dir2>
    </my-dir>  
</div>
```

I would like the second directive (my-dir2) to call the done() function of the first directive (my-dir) which in turn would call the controller one.

Unfortunately I don't know how to make the second directive access the callback of the first directive (so far the second directive is looking inside the high level controller, bypassing the first directive).

I think one could possibly make use of "require" but I can't since the two directives are not related (I want to use my-dir2 inside other directives not only my-dir).

To make it clear : I don't want to use require because it means that there would be a dependency of myDir on myDir2. My point is : I want to be able to reuse myDir2 inside others directives. So I don't want myDir2 to be based on myDir but I do want to inform the upper directive (myDir) when something is done (like in a callback in js).

I have made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xi8tG02XmMVhr0WuJk3Q?p=preview) : as you can see in the javascript console, my-dir2 is calling directly the done function from the high level controller.

Does anyone has a clean way to deal with that kind of situation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

to be able write directives that are independent of each other you need to use events:

1. use `$emit('myEvent', 'myData')` to fire an event that will be handled by scopes that are upward in the hierarchy.
2. use `$broadcast('myEvent', 'myData')` to fire an event that will be handled by scopes that are downward in the hierarchy.
3. to handle the event that was fired by `$emit` or `$broadcast` use `$on('myEvent', function(event, data){\\your code})`

P.S.: in your case the `$emit` won't work because both directives scopes are on the same level in the hierarchy so you will need to use `$rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent' \*, myData*\);` I've updated my plunker to reflect the needed changes http://plnkr.co/edit/eTkO6sk6hpuYPnCjlSKn?p=info

**The following will make inner directive dependent on the outer directive**:

basically to be able to call a function in the first directive you need to do some changes:

1. add `require = '^myDir'` to `myDir2`
2. remove the `onDone` from `myDir2` and keep the isolated scope
   `scope:{}`
3. add controller parameter to link function in `myDir2` `link:
   function(scope,element,attrs,controller)`
4. in `myDir1` controller change the definition of the `done` function
   from `$scope.done` to `this.done`
5. call `controller.done()` in `myDir2`

here is a plunker with the needed changes http://plnkr.co/edit/eTkO6sk6hpuYPnCjlSKn

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately as I said, I don't want to use require because it means that there would be a dependency of myDir on myDir2. My point is : I want to be able to reuse myDir2 inside others directives. So I don't want myDir2 to be based on myDir but I do want to inform the upper directive when something is done.

Comment: @nlko you can use events as a mean of communication between directives, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/158421 it explains the concept in controllers which can be applied to directives too

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for pointing me out this. I think the third solution (emitting an event from the child to the parent where the parent is free to catch it) seems to suit my need. I give you a point (if you prefer create a new answer)!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like these:
angular.element('my-dir').controller('myDir').done();

give a try!