# Parent directive accessing child directive function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say you have 2 directives:

```
<navigation-extended>
    <navigation /> 
</navigation-extended>
```

navigation-extended html template uses transclude property on a div to insert the basic navigation. Besides that, navigation-extended contains extra html (controls to navigate).

What is the best way to access child functionalities from inside the parent directive?

Things I've tried:
 -require ->using this I was able to access navigation-extended methods from inside navigation but not the other way around

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is using `$broadcast` to fire an event in the parent directive and using `$on` to handle it in the child directive, for more info about this check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/158421