# How do I create a globally-available callback API that DOESN'T use $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I want my main module to offer an api which allows any directive, controller, factory, etc. to register a function to be called when a user resizes a div.

Right now I'm successfully doing this by using jQuery's `resizable` callback to update x and y variables on scope then calling `$apply()`. The problem, as you can imagine, is that when a user is dragging a div, it calls the resize callback very rapidly. Rapidly calling $apply() isn't ideal for performance reasons.

I thought about using a service/factory, but there's an indeterminate number of resizable divs/directives and I'm not sure a singleton makes sense here.

Is there a way I can create an "informal" API that doesn't use $scope, doesn't trigger digest cycles, and doesn't use additional libraries? Perhaps there's a way using controllers and `require: ^myCtrl`? Do I need to store all the registered callback functions in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing sounds pretty hacky, so it's probably not a big leap for you to publish angularjs events that get listened to on their scope. So to 'register' a function you listen on the scope for some custom event you create, execute whatever you want in the callback. Get your jquery to broadcast the event on $rootScope.

Have a read about angularjs events
[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)