# Send an event using $emit from directive to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I'm trying to send an event when an item gets selected, from directive to controller using `$emit`. I've two update functions for organizations and another for people. My directive should specify which event should emit.

Here is my update functions:

// For organization

```
 $scope.updateOrgs = function(selectedVal) {
           
 }
```

// For people

```
$scope.updatepeople = function(selectedVal, type) {

}
```

When it is people my directive should raise an emit event for `updatepeople ()`, if it was org it should raise `updateorg()`.

My directive looks like:

```
.directive('search', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            searchobj: '@',
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, index) {
            scope.handleSelection = function (selectedItem) {
                scope.model = selectedItem;
                scope.searchModel="";
                scope.current = 0;
                scope.selected = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.onSelectupdate();
                }, 200);
            };
            scope.Delete = function (index) {
                    scope.selectedIndex = index;
                    scope.delete({ index: index });
            };
            scope.Search = function (searchitem,event,searchobj) {
//                   alert('item entered'+name)
                   scope.searching = searchitem;
                   scope.searchobject = searchobj;
                   scope.onSearch({ searchitem: searchitem , searchobj:searchobj}); 
            };
            scope.current = 0;
            scope.selected = true;
            scope.isCurrent = function (index) {
                return scope.current == index;
            };
            scope.setCurrent = function (index) {
                scope.current = index;
            };
        },
        controller: ['$scope','$element','$rootScope','SearchOrg', function($scope,$element,$rootScope,SearchOrg) {
            $scope.searchItem = function(filter,searchobj){
                //alert('search'+searchobj);
                SearchOrg().fetch({'filter': filter, 'searchType': searchobj}).$promise.then(function(value){
                    $scope.searchData = value.data;
                    console.info($scope.searchData);
                },
                function(err) { 
                });
            }
        }],
        templateUrl: TAPPLENT_CONFIG.HTML_ENDPOINT[0] + 'home/genericsearch.html'
    }
});;
```

HTML snippet

```
<search searchobj=“tei-org” selectedItems=“arrayofIds” search-id=”someidtoIdentify”/>
```

How can I do this both functions are in different controllers, and also I need to send parameters from directive to the controller using `$emit`?

Comment: Where is those two methods for organization & people, defined?

Comment: in different controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)

I'm guessing that your other controllers are not parents, so look at the second option using `$broadcast`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOrgs = []
  $scope.$on('updateorgs', function(evt, data) {
    $scope.selectedOrgs.push(data);
  });
});

app.controller('secondController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedPeople = []
  $scope.$on('updatepeople', function(evt, data) {
    $scope.selectedPeople.push(data);
  });
});

app.directive('someDirective', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.options = [{
        id: 1,
        label: 'org a',
        type: 'org'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'org b',
        type: 'org'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        label: 'person a',
        type: 'person'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        label: 'person b',
        type: 'person'
      }];
      scope.changed = function() {
        if (scope.selected) {
          var updatetype = scope.selected.type; 
          if (updatetype === 'person') {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updatepeople', scope.selected);
          } else if (updatetype === 'org') {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('updateorgs', scope.selected);
          }
        }
      };
    },
    template: '<select ng-change="changed()" ng-model="selected" ng-options="option.label for option in options"><option value="">Select</option></select>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <some-directive></some-directive>
  <div ng-controller='firstController'>
    <div>ORGS:</div>
    <div>
      {{ selectedOrgs }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='secondController'>
    <div>PEOPLE:</div>
    <div>
      {{ selectedPeople }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```