# scope.$parent.messageContent= value not updating the parent scope from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I could have sworn I had this working earlier but now I just cannot get the parent scope to update and display on the page.

In the parent I have some a simple scope I want to update from the directive.
In the parent controller I set it like this.

```
$scope.messageContent = 'The initial content';
```

In the parent view I have it displayed

```
{{$scope.messageContent}}
```

I made it very simple for a test and here is the directive.  In my link function in the directive I have this code:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$parent.messageContent = 'New content';
}
```

It simply will not update the parent.  What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: You can try emit and broadcast http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999407/send-an-event-using-emit-from-directive-to-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an `ng-if` or another Angular directive (ng-repeat, ng-switch, ...) that creates a new scope, so you have to go up the chain with more `$parent` declarations.

Better option is to use an object.

**Controller**:

```
$scope.message = {content: 'some content'};
```

**Directive**

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.message.content = 'New content';
}
```

Using an object instead of a primitive to solve the resolution problem works due to JavaScript's prototypal inheritance.
For a detailed answer - see this: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: SHould this be scope.$parent.message.content = 'New content';   ?

Comment: No, in JS prototypal inheritance objects are treated differently than primitives.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Doesn't work however.  Cannot set property 'content' of undefined.  I get that in my directive.   Please note the controller in this case is in the parent.  Not the controller in directive. I am only using Link in the directive.

Comment: Is the directive set to have an isolate scope?