# Creating emitter to talk between angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularfire with the yeoman generator and have a working logout function in my account controller:

```
  $scope.logout = function() { Auth.$unauth(); };
```

Where Auth is:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('firebase.auth', ['firebase', 'firebase.ref'])

  .factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, Ref) {
    return $firebaseAuth(Ref);
  });
})();
```

That part works great. I would like to make a logout button in the nav bar but since that is in a different scope, I need to make an emitter in my nav controller:

```
$scope.logout = $scope.$emit('loggedOut');
```

In my account controller, I listen for emitted signal. Both of these ways do not work:

```
$scope.$on('loggedOut', function() { Auth.$unauth(); });
$scope.$on('loggedOut', $scope.logout );
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?
Thanks!

EDIT- I updated my code but I still have issues:

```
angular.module('rutileApp')
  .controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope, user, Auth, Ref, $firebaseObject, $timeout) {
    $scope.logout = function() { Auth.$unauth(); };

    $scope.$on('loggedOut', function(event, msg) {
      $scope.logout();
    });
});

angular.module('rutileApp')
  .controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.sendLogout = function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedOut', {msg: 'logging out'});
    }

  });
```

I cannot see the broadcasted signal in the AccountCtrl scope even if it is just to console.log something so it isn't a problem with the logout function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
I kept my original answer down below, but here is an updated plunker that demonstrates calling a logout function by broadcast (but you must have an instance of that controller already loaded in order to access it).  I also show how you can put the logout function inside a factory, which you can then inject into your controller and call from anywhere, and there is no need to have any particular controller instantiated.

Also, just looking at your code, I don't see why you can't call your Auth service directly - just inject `Auth` into your NavCtrl and add the logout function there like you did in the AccountCtrl : 
`$scope.logout = function() {Auth.$unauth();}`

It's the same thing..no reason to call the AccountCtrl method when you can access that factory from anywhere.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6C4eT8K7ttGTpUnozBsF?p=preview)

Factory:

```
angular.module('rutileApp')
  .factory('accountFactory', function() {
    return {
      logout: function() {
        console.log('called logout from somewhere')
        return 'called logout from somewhere';
      }

    }
  })
```

---

You should do `$rootScope.broadcast('logout', msg);`

As others mentioned - $emit fires events from child scopes **upwards** to parent scopes.  $broadcast fires events **downwards** to child scopes.  But in the case of sibling scopes, **neither of these will work**.  Every scope is a child of $rootScope, and we can access $rootScope from anywhere by injecting it into our controller.  Therefore you want to fire your event down from $rootScope to child scopes.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('logout', function(event, msg) {
    $scope.msg = msg.msg
    console.log(msg.msg);
  })
});
app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.sendLogout = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('logout', {msg: 'logging out now!'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I click the button, I can get a console.log in my $scope.sendLogout function to fire off but I cannot see the console.log fire in my MainCtrl. Consequentially, I don't log off. Is there something else to watch for?

Comment: you are calling the logout method inside the scope.$on ?

Comment: It's probably because you don't have the AccountCtrl instantiated.
Truth be told, you should have your logout function in a factory anyway.  Then you could just call it without doing $broadcast.

See here, I have it working using your code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/a0gnFxxQiXTkueXsePxJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If the nav controller and the account controller don't have a parent-child `$scope` relationship (if the tags on which the controllers are instantiated aren't nested), the `$scope.$emit('event')` will never work.

In Angular, the events can be emitted both with `$emit` (that dispatches the event to the parent scopes of the emitter) and with `$broadcast` (that dispatches the event to the child scopes of the emitter).

A workaround to your problem, is using `$rootScope.$broadcast` that will dispatch the event to all the scopes of the application. Not elegant but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is a scope hierarchy issue because of which the event handlers are not been called.

In Angular $emit, sends the events upwards and $broadcast downwards the scope hierarchy.

The nav controller scope has to be child scope of account controller for `$emit` to work.

The better option would be to use `$rootScope.$broadcast` which would be received by every controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

$emit only bubbles up to the parent scope, so it's not going to work unless your account controller is a parent to your nav controller. You can use $broadcast if it is a child. If there is no relation, it has to be on the $rootScope. Longer answer: [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)