# How to destroy $emit and $broadcast events in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Plnkr example build: http://plnkr.co/edit/gB7MtVOOHH0FBJYa6P8t?p=preview**

[Following the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on), I created some `$broadcast` events to allow actions in the main `$scope` to close popovers in sub `$scopes`. However I want to make sure I clean up all my events and not have anything lingering that should not.

I have a popover directive, once the popover is activated I send out:

```
vs.$emit('popoverOpen');
```

Then in the main app module ($rootScope), I listen for it here:

```
vs.$on('popoverOpen',function(events,data) {

    // if 'popoverOpen' is heard, then activate this function
    // which on click $broadcasts out even 'bodyClick'
    // but also destroy the 'popoverOpen' event
    vs.bodyClick = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('bodyClick');
        $rootScope.$$listenerCount.popoverOpen=[];
    };
});
```

Back in the popover Directive, here is my `bodyClick` listener:

```
vs.$on('bodyClick', function() {
    vs.searchPopoverDisplay = false;
    $rootScope.$$listenerCount.bodyClick=[];
});
```

^ I also have code in there attempting to kill the `bodyClick` event, however to no avail :(

As you can see below, I've removed `bodyClick` and `popoverOpen` from the `$$listenerCount` (there was never anything in the `$$listener` object.

However the user is still able to access the `vs.bodyClick()` function in the main app rootScope, even though `popoverOpen` should have been removed.

---

**So on first load:**

- If the user clicks around without opening any popover, `bodyClick` is never captured / transmitted
- After opening a popover, `bodyClick` is active
- If the user clicks on the body, that event is sent out and closes the popover
- However, now even with NO popovers open, if the user clicks on the body that `bodyClick` event keeps getting sent out

---

[image]

How would you properly remove the events after the `bodyClick` event has been sent out to close the popover?

---

**UPDATE**
I also tried this (https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#publish-and-subscribe-events), but still the bodyClick event keeps getting sent out after the popover is closed and supposedly destroyed.

*popoverDirective function still gets called:*

```
vs.$on('bodyClick', function() {

    console.log('bodyClick received ...');
    console.log($rootScope.$$listener);
    console.log($rootScope.$$listenerCount);

    vs.searchPopoverDisplay = false;

    var unbind = $rootScope.$on('popoverOpen', []);
    vs.$on('$destroy', unbind);
    // $rootScope.$$listenerCount.bodyClick=[];
});
```

[image]

Comment: There is a note on Todd Motto's Angular guide that mentions destroying publish and subscribe events. It might be what you are looking for. https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#publish-and-subscribe-events

Comment: Thanks! Hmm I tried out his `destroy` code, but didn't work.. had to also fix a syntax error there, but still no luck... added what I tried above.

Comment: Building a plnkr example now http://plnkr.co/edit/gB7MtVOOHH0FBJYa6P8t?p=preview

Comment: So, I added a console to your `$destroy` listener in your plunkr and it never gets called. So then I added a `$scope.$destroy()` after your `bodyClick` call, and poof! No more alerts. Not sure if it has the desired after effect though... [my plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0EDELIikFRQgdmrV8GM5?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes about your plunkr:

1. None of your controllers go out of scope, thus none of them emit
   `$destroy`.
2. You're listening for `$destroy` but attempting to
   emit `destroy`, which isn't the same. Remove the `$` from the
   listener and you'll see the callback running.
3. Because `subController` is a child of `mainController` destroying main destroys both and stops the button, along with everything else. This behavior is shown in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0EDELIikFRQgdmrV8GM5?p=preview).

So in order to get the pseudo-`$destroy` to ping, I changed it to listen on just `destroy`.

Then, instead of calling your unbind, which wouldn't work in this case as we aren't actually `$destroy`ing anything, I simply replaced the `bodyClick` function, as it is bound to the `<body>`.

```
$scope.$on('destroy', function() {
  $scope.bodyClick = angular.noop();
});
```

This seems to have the desired effect. **Updated** [Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qILnECIZzql2cFzp2S69?p=preview).

**Update**: I discovered why it was indefinitely adding listeners...! The `destroy` listener was *in* the button callback. So each button press would add yet another callback. I moved the `destroy` listener outside of the `popover` listener. No more memory leaking!

Comment: Oh, that is what I'm trying to do, how do you destroy the scope for real? Thanks for the first part.. I wanted to stop a function from getting called, but I also don't want anymore events being called when they are not needed.

Comment: Simply: `$scope.$destroy();`

Comment: Yes, I've been mulling over this plunkr **a lot**. I think its structure is making it extremely difficult to really give you a solid answer. For example, you set a `$scope` function in the callback we're trying to unbind, which won't actually unset that variable, so the method still exists. Hopefully this can push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, yeah now I'm looking at your plnkr and the alert never comes back when the user clicks the button. Alert only happens once, but it should alert everytime the button is clicked, just not on the rest of the body. I'll play with this... thanks!

Comment: Like I amended, the button is a child of the controller you're looking to destroy! So taking out the parent will also remove the children. I was expecting the button to be a sibling to main, not a child. _hint hint_

Comment: @LeonGaban I found the major issue in the plunkr. I've updated the link. The issue is that we were listening for our destroy in the callback of the button press. Doh!

Comment: Thanks man! This is brilliant, I understand why it works in your plunk, just not sure why it doesn't in my code :( mind taking a moment to see if anything stands out in these 2 gists?                                                     `main`: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/bc3110add6d484c7d982 | `sub`: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/a603b08941d69ab96e8c for example in my code, I still see the console logs when I click on the body, even when the popover has already been hidden. The popover is turned on in line `73` of the 2nd gist file.

Comment: Main:Line 75. Change `vs.$on('$destroy'...)` to `vs.$on('destroy'...)` Or maybe add `destroy` just to have both. haha

Comment: GOT IT! `vs.bodyClick = angular.noop();` Needed to do that, I guess I thought `vs` was trying to use `$scope` and `$rootScope`, but finally got it working... updated that 1 line in my main file and boom :) event gone when popover is gone, and comes back when popover is turned on again :D thanks for all the help!