# How to pass data in controller Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers:

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
   <div ng-controller="Map"></div>
</div>
```

In controller `Main` I have variable `$scope.mapCoord;`
How I can to pass this variable in controller `Map`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with $scope.$emit and .$on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a service. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var mapCoord= 'Test';

    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            return mapCoord;
        },
        setProperty: function(value) {
            mapCoord= value;
        }
    };
});
```

Inside your Main controller

```
app.controller('Main', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.mapCoord= sharedProperties.setProperty("Main"); 
});
```

Inside your Map controller

```
app.controller('Map', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.mapCoord= sharedProperties.getProperty(); 
});
```

Here's a fiddle for you. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0a96kc6/1/)

Comment: It's probably some other error on your side. Check out my Fiddle. It's working perfectly fine. Post your angular code.

Comment: In your exmaple there are two controllers, but they are separated, I have controller inside controller

Comment: At first I get value from AJAX and after I do: `setProperty(objFromAjax);`. But controller `Map` works faster that AJAX returns data

Comment: You need to bind an element in your view to the property of your $scope object. Once the $scope object is updated after the AJAX request is complete, the view should be updated automatically.

Comment: Can yoy give me example how do it?

Answer (score 0):

You use events to pass it between controllers using by `$broadcast`, `$emit` and `$on`

[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)

http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2013/12/28/sharing-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs-pubsub-event-bus-example/

Answer (score 0):

In your "Map" controller, set "Main" scope to current scope such as below :

```
app.controller('Map', ['$scope','$controller',function($scope, $controller) {

    $controller('Main', {
        $scope : $scope
    });
}]);
```

After that you can access all the scope of Main controller from his son controller :

```
app.controller('Map', ['$scope','$controller',function($scope, $controller) {

    $controller('Main', {
        $scope : $scope
    });

    var coord = $scope.mapCoord;
}]);
```

Comment: Look please comment to previos question, I use AJAX and it puts $scope, but controller `Map` works faster

Comment: OK, remember to complete your initial question to help next person understand the problem.