# How to call a function in a controller from a different controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking on how to force a controller to refresh from another controller.

for that I'm using a simple test function :

```
function test() { alert('test'); }
```

I think using events is the best solution for this issue.

I used the following code :

First controller

```
.controller('firstcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
$scope.$emit('testevent'); })
```

Second controller

```
.controller('firstcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
   $scope.$on('refreshr', function (event) {
        alert('test');
    }); })
```

but this is not working ! any advice ?

Comment: In the provided code, both event does not have same names ('testevent', 'refreshr' ?, both controller have same name ('firstcontroller')?

Comment: See this answer to a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502755/2509908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `event names` are different, also broadcast on `rootScope` level.

```
.controller('firstcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('testevent'); 
})

.controller('secondcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
   $scope.$on('testevent', function (event) {
        alert('test');
   }) 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use $rootScope.$broadcast function to broadcast event to all child scopes. And then in you controller you do $scope.$on. But make sure that name of events are the same.

This should be it.

First controller

```
.controller('firstcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('testevent'); 
})
```

Second controller

```
.controller('secondcontroller', function($rootScope,$scope, $http,$timeout) {
   $scope.$on('testevent', function (event) {
        alert('test');
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! can you please give an example according to my code !