# Passing id to json data in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to create a chat application through angular and php.
I have created 2 controllers.

One is for displaying the number of peoples online and other controllers is for sending and recieving messages.

In MainController I can show the person name whom I clicked but in SendMessageController I don't know how to show the same person name.

Please help me, I'm new to angular. 
here is working [`Plunker Link`](http://plnkr.co/edit/5MBRr7zlfJYliypKE8zK?p=preview)

Comment: make a service to the veriable name of person clicked. Now create getter and setter to get the name of person clicked.

Comment: Or you could do it through events see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use service to share the data between controllers.
Inject the service to both controllers.

```
app.service('userService', function() {

    this.userId = '';

    this.setUserId = function(id) {
        this.userId = id;
    };

    this.getUserId = function() {
        return this.userId;
    };

}
```

[Full example](https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424)