# How do I get $emit to controller from directive built html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I'm having difficulty figuring this out. I have a directive building html from promise data. For each row, it's adding buttons for CRUD operations. I do not know how to get the button event to trigger in my controller. Regardless of how my controller is set up, how can I get the event to register in my controller? I am currently trying `$emit`, but nothing seems to happen.

Directive generated html:

```
controls = controls+'<button type="button" data-tooltip-placement="bottom" data-tooltip="'+action.name+'" ng-click="$emit(&apos;'+action.broadcaster+'&apos;,'+rowId+')" name="'+action.name+'" class="btn btn-xs btn-default ng-scope"><i class="'+action.icon+'"></i> </button>'
```

How it looks in Chrome tools:

```
<button type="button" data-tooltip-placement="bottom" data-tooltip="delete" ng-click="$emit('removeOrgCourse',134)" name="delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-default ng-scope"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </button>
```

and my controller listener:

```
$scope.$on('removeOrgCourse', function( event, data ){
     console.log(data);
});
```

UPDATE:
Just changed the ng-click to `console.log("click")` and nothing happened. So the issue is that ng-click is not registering;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use events in angular to achive that, one other option is to use `&` expression scope binding to pass controller method to directive. Example code (from [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding))(see working code at [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cukaka/6/edit?html,js,output)):

```
<div ng-app="phoneApp">
<!-- we've replaced the use of $scope with the preferred "controller as" syntax. see:http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ -->
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appctrl">
    <div phone dial="appctrl.callHome(message)"></div>
    <div phone dial="appctrl.callHome(message)"></div>
    <div phone dial="appctrl.callHome(message)"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    app.controller("AppCtrl", function() {
        var appctrl = this;
        appctrl.callHome = function(message) {
            alert(message);
        };
    });
```

And directive:

```
 app.directive("phone", function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                dial: "&"
            },
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value">' +
              '<div class="button" ng-click="dial({message:value})">Call home!</div>'
        };
    });
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, although it does not resolve my issue. I have found that my issue is related to ng-click and $compile. ng-click doesn't work at all, and when I $compile the html, it breaks other code. I think this has do specifically with jquery datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use $broadcast, depends if the controllers are on the same level or who's over who.

[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)

http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

in the secon link you can put the $emit and $broadcast in the same controller and see whad do you catch in you $on

Comment: In this case $emit was the correct option. The problem I have is ng-click and $compile not working.