# Use of $scope.$on() function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJs. 
I saw this **$scope.$on()** function.
I can't understand this. can you explain me

Comment: $scope.$on is paired with $scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit. See this question for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a general purpose reference, but the [tool you are using has its own](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation).

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$on` is used to listed to events triggered by

```
  $scope.$broadcast
```

or

```
  $scope.$emit
```