# how to display data in one controller when an click event occurred in other controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular.js. I just want to display "Welcome" message which is 'ControllerB' when clicking a button which is in 'ControllerA'. I tried this by using 'service' but I didn't get how to do.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script/service.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller='contA'>

        <input type="button" ng-click="clicked()" value="Click">

    </div>
    <div ng-controller='contB'>
        <div ng-show="clickShow">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('contA', ['$scope', 'displayServ', function(scope,displayServ){        
    scope.clicked = function(){
        displayServ.disp = true;            
    }       
}]);

app.controller('contB',['$scope', 'displayServ', function(scope,displayServ){        
    scope.clickShow = displayServ.disp;       
}]);

app.service('displayServ', function(){
    this.disp = false;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to bind to `disp` property of the service object directly because `scope.clickShow` is not going to change by itself - there is no connection between service `disp` and scope `clickShow`.

So you can expose service object directly into template:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('contA', ['$scope', 'displayServ', function(scope,displayServ){        
    scope.clicked = function(){
        displayServ.disp = true;            
    }
}]);

app.controller('contB',['$scope', 'displayServ', function(scope,displayServ){        
    scope.displayServ = displayServ;       
}]);

app.service('displayServ', function(){
    this.disp = false;
});
```

and in template then:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script/service.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller='contA'>
        <input type="button" ng-click="clicked()" value="Click">    
    </div>
    <div ng-controller='contB'>
        <div ng-show="displayServ.disp">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Otherwise you would have to use `scope.$watch`, but this is not recommend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $Broadcast to show the effect in the other controller