# Angular - affect parent page

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app which will display an image from an array for instance

```
images[$scope.activeIndex]
```

On the page is a link that will do a window open popup and on this popup page will be a next button. How does the child page affect the parent page. So the next button will call a function on the parent page which will increase the $scope.activeIndex by 1 and change some other scope values, which changes the image on the parent page

Answer (score 0):

Typically communication between controllers is done via events. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on) for more detail.

In general, the child controller fires an event on the button click then the parent controller handles the event.