# How to define angularjs variables inside script

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i am using simple *get method*

```
var self= this;
self.items = [];
var fetchGraphs = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/graph').then(
                    function(response) {
                            self.items = response.data;
                            alert(self.items);
                    }, function(errResponse) {
                            console.error('Error while fetching notes');
                    });
         };`
```

to get the following JSON data.

```
{
 "Msg": "Running",
 "excMsg": null,
 "array1": {
        "key1": 32,
        "key2": 10,
        "key3": 24
    },

 "array2": {
        "key4": 42,
        "key5": 20,
        "key5": 22
    }}
```

Now I have to draw graph for array1 and array2. for that i have to declare the values from *get method inside script* itself.but its giving me error for

> "can not read  key1 property."

Can anyone please tell me how to declare array variables that I get from JSON in the another script file

Comment: you can call a function with json data when response is success

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "declare" variables direct. You must use method or subscribe to event. The easy solution scope.emit and etc. See here: 
[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)
If you want to use fetchGraphs for example (your method).

```
fetchGraphs().then(function(result) {
   // do something with result array 
});
```

Edit:

If you post more code people here can help you effective.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `then` method from fetchGraph or else return data from success method of `$http`.

My recommendation, you can keep watch on the `self.items`. so whenever it change you can re-draw your graph.

```
$scope.$watch(
    "self.items",
     function () {
          //re-draw your graph
          $scope.$apply(); // not needed always, just a precaution
      }
);
```