# What's the difference in Angular when execute same function in different document segments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular and added a button in index.html:

```
<button ng-controller = "studentCtrl" ng-click="$emit('update')">refresh</button>
```

When clicked, the model has been updated but the view not, even `$digest` has been executed. When I add the same button in the `templateURL` of `studentCtrl`, it works fine. I try to move the button to `ng-view` `div` but it still fails, so can anyone tell me the difference?

The `templateURL` for `studentCtrl` is

```
<tr ng-controller="studentCtrl" ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="$emit('update')">refresh</button></td>
</tr>
```

and the `studentCtrl` is

```
.controller('studentCtrl', ['$scope', 'baseDataUrl', '$http', '$timeout', 
    function($scope, baseDataUrl, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.update = function() {
        $http.get(baseDataUrl).then(function(res) {
           $scope.students = res.data;
        });
     };
     $scope.update();

     //when switch to student app, get all students data first
     $scope.$on("update", function() {
         //for test
         $scope.students = [];
     });
  }]);
```

Comment: You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Answer (score 0):

$emit() dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy, from child to parent.It should use from child controller to parent controller, you can simply call update method for click event.

```
<button ng-controller = "studentCtrl" ng-click="update()">refresh</button>
```

Comment: In fact the event has been listened successfully, only the view hasn't been updated, i mean the view binded with $scope.students. Also your code doesn't work, the behavior is same, the $scope.students has changed but the view hasn't. Also I want to know how you define scope hierarchy, or what can i search to study this.

Answer (score 0):

use `$scope.$apply()` to update the view. `$emit` and `$broadcast` is used as delegate, works based on some event-handler concept between controllers, That's not required I guess in your example , so you can simply write your controller

```
.controller('studentCtrl', ['$scope', 'baseDataUrl', '$http', '$timeout', 
function($scope, baseDataUrl, $http, $timeout) {
   // define your scope varibales
    $scope.students = [];

    $scope.update = function() {
        /// update the students collection
       };
  }]);
```