# $scope.$emit not work in callback?

Tags: angularjs, callback, angularjs-scope, emit

I have a code to authentication where I want call an event after receive some data, but "$scope.$emit" not working in the callback of "User.me()" and I not understand.

Anybody can explain me?

```
$scope.login = function () {
    OAuth.getAccessToken($scope.user).then(function () {

        $scope.$emit('event:here:work');
        User.me({}, {}, function (data) {
            $scope.$emit('event:here:NOT-WORK');
        });
        $scope.$emit('event:here:work');

    }, function (response) {
        // error //
    });
};
```

I try:

```
$scope.$emit('event');          // but, not work
$scope.$broadcast('event');     // but, not work
$rootScope.$emit('event');      // but, not work
$rootScope.$broadcast('event'); // work!!!!
```

Now, the "why" I not know?

Comment: Is the callback actually called? Did you try placing logging / debugging using both success and error callback?

Comment: The login is success and "User.me()" too. The login callback run "$scope.$emit" like expected, but the callback of "User.me()" not dispatch "$scope.$emit".

Comment: May be a stupid question but where do you call the callback function?

Comment: The answer can find from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.$broadcast` instead.