# Angular, communicate between modules

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast, emit

I have fallowing setup for my project:

- mainApp main angular module, containing EventBus factory
- app1 first module with mainApp injected
- app2 second module with mainApp injected

app1 and app2 are two modules placed on the same page, both have mainApp injected.

I am trying to communicate between app1 and app2 using EventBus factory, which is defined in mainApp. 
Unfortunately, I can't get it to work (app1 doesn't catch app2 event, and opposite).

How should I resolve that? Have I take a wrong approach?

```
EventBus.subscribe("App1Ctr.event", function (event, data) {
    console.log("App2handler");
    $scope.name = data.newVal;
});


$scope.fireEvent = function () {
    EventBus.broadcast("App2Ctr.event", {"newVal": "App2Ctr"});
};
```

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZpdmdOvHve3y0OsF2nON?p=preview)

Comment: Can you please add a little bit detail something like: 1) What is your expected output/behavior?   2) What is current output/behavior?

Comment: @KhalidHussain expected output: I have several modules and want all of them to listen for events send from one main(injected) module. 
current output - no events caught neither in app1 nor app2

Comment: Can you please just add a `console.log` in your plnkr and print current output?

Comment: updated this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ZpdmdOvHve3y0OsF2nON?p=preview

it looks like broadcast is fired up correctly but subscription doesn't work.

Comment: Just a little bit more info, specify a `console log` where current output is wrong and mention your expected output. It will be better if you [edit] all the information into your question.

Comment: the problem is the EvenBus.subscribe handler is not run after event is broadcasted, so there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way dependencies are injected. Your `main.js` needs to contain this:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["app1", "app2"])
```

Your two `app1.js` and `app2.js` can drop the dependency requirement from `mainApp`:

```
var app1 = angular.module("app1", [])
```

and

```
var app2 = angular.module("app2", [])
```

Your initialization code in `index.html` becomes

```
<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["mainApp"]);
    });
</script>
```

You will need to change the references to `{{name}}`, too, so that they include a dot (because of the whole prototypical inheritance thing in angular). See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8iy0bZpIMQD6iKzwndXw?p=preview), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14502006/1159164) for more details on `$broadcast`, `$emit`, `$on`, and `$rootScope`.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I can't do this, as this would up-side-down the project structure.

Comment: your `main.js` currently only contains a factory for `EventBus`, so you might as well rename it to `eventBus.js`. The alternative is to make your `app1` and `app2` children of a common parent, use `$scope.$emit` on the children, and have that parent re-broadcast events down the hierarchy using `$scope.$broadcast`, like it's shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358365/1159164)

Comment: The example works with different controllers, but how do I nest angular apps/modules?

Comment: I've edited [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8wrFmOtRCBFIAhjykgUe?p=preview) to show you the standard way of dealing with multi-module angular apps (replacing the manual bootstrap part with `ng-app`). That's just how you usually define the modules of your app, you list them as dependencies for your main module.

Comment: Thnks, but as I said, I can't do this that way, The project is really big and containing many angular apps, I can't revert the structure of all project now, as it will break lot of other functionality. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. The broadcast method in EventBus should look something like:

```
_broadcast = function(eventName, data) {
    console.log("EventBus broadcast: " + eventName);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('app1')).scope().$root.$emit(eventName, data);
  };
```

Since it has to get angular app by ID, I will use in addition EventDispatcher to handle this.