# How to trigger an event in one view from a different view?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to open an Angular accordian in the `header.html` by clicking a button which is in the `body.html`. Essentially triggering an event in one view from a completely different view. Does anyone have any idea how to do this in Angular?

Comment: You can broadcast an event from the controller for the HTML page with the button to the controller for the page with the dropdown.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on).

Comment: Or just set a flag in $rootScope.

Comment: this has been answered so many times on stackoverflow. I know because I've answered about 3 of them

Comment: $rootScope flag, shared service or broadcasted event.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: LordTribual. Sorry for the late response. Yes it did. I have marked it as the answer. Btw thank you to all of you for your input! I am now trying to figure out how to get a $timeout function to work to close it. Will make a new question. Thank you again.

Comment: Let me know if I can help you there as well.

Comment: Solved. I appreciate it though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519009/issues-with-getting-timeout-function-to-work/37519398?noredirect=1#comment62533219_37519398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using events to let your accordion directive know that something happend or use a shared service. Considering the performance, it does not make a huge difference, but only if you use `$emit` instead of `$broadcast` since the event fired via `$emit` bubbles up your scope hierarchy and `$broadcast` sends the event down. Also make sure to fire the event on the `$rootScope`, so it won't event bubble up anymore.

So you in case you want to use events for you could have a method on your component that fires the event via `$emit` on the `$rootScope` as follows:

```
function openAccordion() {
    $rootScope.$emit('on-accordion-open', null);
}
```

You could then use this in your view, e.g. in `body.html`. Remember that function above is part of another directive / component or controller.

```
<button ng-click="vm.openAccordion()">Open Accordion</button>
```

Also note that I assume you are using `controllerAs` syntax (set to `vm`).

In your accordion directive you can then hook up listeners to several events for example the `on-accordion-open`:

```
$rootScope.$on('on-accordion-open', function() {
    // Open the accordion
});
```

The other soltuion is to use a shared service. In this case I would create a `AccordionServce` that is aware of all instances of accordions. The service could look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('AccordionService', function() {
   var accordions = {};

   this.addAccordion = function(name, accordion) {
       accordions[name] = accordion;
   };

   this.removeAccordion = function(name) {
       delete accordions[name];
   };

   this.getAccordion = function(name) {
       return accordions[name];
   };
});
```

In your accordion's controller you then add the accordion to the `AccordionService` via

```
accordionService.addAccordion('myAccordion', this);
```

The `this` in the snippet above is refering to the accordion controller. Thats important because if you then get an accordion in your component in the `body.html`, you'll get the controller instance and can call methods like `open`.

So in your body component you can then inject the `AccordionService` and get the accordion to call a method:

```
accordionService.getAccordion('myAccordion').open();
```

Make sure to define `open` on the accordion's controller.