# Issues with getting $timeout function to work

Tags: angularjs

I have created a plunkr with my code that does work. After the drop down is collapsed by clicking the Toggle collapse button, I need the dropdown to close on it's own after 3 seconds. I have played with the following in the HeaderCtrl in example.js with no luck:

```
function callAtTimeout(){
  $scope.isFooCollapsed = true;
}

$timeout(function(){ 
  !$scope.callAtTimeout();
}, 3000);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wMxA4Tkiqr9BsSfxia02?p=preview

Any help/input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you inject `$timeout` to the dependencies list of the controller?

Comment: I don't see any timeout code in plunkr?

Comment: Hi TJ. Per your request, I have edited the question with the updated plunkr. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why I am getting down voted for my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use angular `$timeout` to achieve the wanted like this:

```
var timer;
$scope.isFooCollapsed = true;
$rootScope.$on("bagNotification", function() {
  $timeout.cancel(timer);
  $scope.isFooCollapsed = !$scope.isFooCollapsed;
  timer = $timeout(function() {
    $scope.isFooCollapsed = true;
  }, 3000);
});
```

We cancel the timeout each time with `$timeout.cancel` to prevent multiple hide/shows when button is clicked multiple times.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YbsCuicDiHVDGULwpap3?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much thepio! The cancel on the timer was not needed in my case. Because even if someone clicked on the toggle button multiple times, for my use case, I would actually want the dropdown to show just as many times. The following plain vanilla code from your original answer worked for me. Thanks again. For anyone reading here is the code I speak of.

Comment: $scope.isFooCollapsed = true;
      $rootScope.$on("bagNotification", function() {
        $scope.isFooCollapsed = !$scope.isFooCollapsed;
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.isFooCollapsed = !$scope.isFooCollapsed;
        }, 3000);
      });

Comment: No problem. Good to hear you got what you wanted and that I could be helpful to you :)