# angularjs - $rootScope.$on called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

In one controller I do :

```
$rootScope.$emit("newAction", {});
```

in another controller I do :

```
$rootScope.$on('newAction', function() {
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
      });
```

My problem is that $rootScope.$on is called multiple times. I don't know why.

If anybody has a hint...
Thanks

Comment: `newAction` is a function you call multiple times? Show the code that surrounds the `$rootScope.$emit`

Comment: Hi, in controller 2, use $scope for detect "newAction".

Answer (score 19):

`$rootScope` listener are not destroyed automatically. You need to destroy it using `$destroy`.

```
var customeEventListener = $rootScope.$on('newAction', function() {
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
          vm.newAction (...);
      });

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        customeEventListener();
  });
```

Refer this link 
[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on/36377476#36377476)