# $scope is not refreshing after value changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have service module which read JSON file and returns JSON data.
Here is code

```
angular.module('serviceModule').service('dataService',["$http",function($http){
return {
    getData:function(file){
        return $http.get('url to json file').then(function(response) {

            return response.data;              
 });                        
    }
```

I am getting this data in my directive and assigning it to my $scope variable.

```
angular.module('xyz').directive('xyz',function(dataService){
  return {
   templateUrl:'hfhf',
   controller:'hgf',
   link:function($scope){
        console.log("Hi");

               $scope.tasks=[];
      dataService.getData('location to json file').then(function(data){
         $scope.tasks=data;
      });
```

so my main problem is I have another controller  which is changing value at '**location to JSON value**',but this change is not reflecting immediately when I refresh the web page then only those change are reflecting.
I have tried implementing with watcher but it throws ERROR continuously and my browser becomes unresponsive.
Can anyone please help me to reflect changes immediately when change happens in '**location to JSON value**'

My HTML directive as asked by some of you .In directive, i am doing

```
<div ng-repeat='task in tasks track by $index' class="xyzwell"data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" data-drag="true" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:'true', animate: true,onStop:'dragStopCall()'}" id='{{$index}}' >
<div class="editIcon " >

    <div class="pull-right">
<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
    </div>
<div class="taskDetailarea">
    <p>{{$index}} {{dragStopCall}}</p>
<p>{{task.xy}}</p>
    <p>{{task.abc}}</p>
    <p>{{task.bcd}}</p>
</div>
```

Here I am using ngDragDrop thats why I have added those tags those are working fine.I am just iterating through tasks thats all.

Comment: Show your `html` template of directive.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko sure if u required i will add this

Comment: Can u please share th controller how it is changing the data?

Comment: What kind of error happens, when you using `watcher`?

Comment: Watcher listening expressions need to be synchronous. They don't work with asynchronous services. Is the other controller which is posting data to the url using the `dataService` service? The directive needs to be notified by the service when changes are made to the url of interest.

Comment: @georgeawg yes, i am using dataService only to posting data to URL but from a different controller.I don't know how to notify when data change happens to URL and make use of this.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko I am using the same service to reflect changes from the different controller so I don't think it is necessary to post code for the different controller.

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your issue, but take a look at $broadcast/$emit and $on. When your controller makes a change, publish a message with $broadcast or $emit, and then wire up your directive to listen for that event using $on. Here is a great SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on

Comment: @TimHobbs Thanks with this great link i am able to figure out and now its working .Please post your suggestion as answer i will mark it accept

Comment: @ivan - Glad it worked out for you. I posted my comment as an answer and added a little borrowed text from the original SO link to illustrate the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked, I am posting my comment as an answer since it worked for the OP.

> I am not sure if I completely understand your issue, but take a look at $broadcast/$emit and $on. When your controller makes a change, publish a message with $broadcast or $emit, and then wire up your directive to listen for that event using $on. Here is a great SO link: [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/)

I'll borrow from the link to give an overview here as well:

`$broadcast` -- dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes

`$emit` -- dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.

So a quick example of the usage would be:

```
function firstCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
}

function secondCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) { console.log(mass); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i am using `dataService` only to posting data to URL but from a different controller.I don't know how to notify when data change happens to URL and make use of this

There are several approaches to this problem. One is to keep a local copy in the service and use a watcher on the local copy.

```
app.service('dataService',function($http){
    var dataService = this;
    this.localCopy = {};
    this.getData = function(url){
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
            dataService.localCopy[url] = response.data;                
            return response.data;              
        });                        
    };
    this.postData = function(url, data) {
        dataService.localCopy[url] = data;
        return $http.post(url,data).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

The directive can put a watcher on the local copy of the data.

```
app.directive('xyz',function(dataService){
    return {
       templateUrl:'hfhf',
       controller:'hgf',
       link: function(scope){
            console.log("Hi");
            dataService.getData(url);
            scope.$watch(
                function() {return dataService.localCopy[url]},
                function (newValue) { scope.tasks = newValue;}
            );
       }
    }
});
```

By watching the local copy of the data in the service, the directive will see the changes created by other users of the service.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
dataService.getData('location to json file').then(function(data){
         $scope.tasks=data;
         $scope.$apply();
      });
```

This will force a digest cycle and update all your watchers making sure the changes in scope are reflected in your view.

[This blog post explains more](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%24scope.%24apply()%3B&oq=%24scope.%24apply()%3B&aqs=chrome..69i57.223j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I have tried this but its throwing ERROR for more info about ERROR 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest