# how to pass value from diffrent controller angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I want to pass value from ng-click inside button, to athor html page (controller).
I have one page with 'getPersonalCtrl' controller that get my vaue from ng-click,
and want to sent this value to athor controller 'viewPersonalCtrl' in a diffrent html page, but I cant get the value.

this is my getPersonalCtrl (controller):

```
mymedical.controller('getPersonalCtrl',['$scope','$http','$cookies','myService',function($scope,$http,$cookies,myService) {

$scope.viewCurrent = function(value){
  $scope.information = value;
   myService.setInfo($scope.information);

  ///window.location="viewDetails.html";
}

}]);
```

this is my viewPersonalCtrl (controller) that I want to send the data to:

```
mymedical.controller('viewPersonalCtrl',['$scope','$http','$cookies','myService', function($scope,$http,$cookies,myService){
    $scope.myreturnedData = myService.getInfo();
    console.log($scope.myreturnedData);
}]);

mymedical.factory('myService', function(){
  console.log("factory");
var infoObj = null;//the object to hold our data
     return {
     getInfo:function(){
      console.log("getInfo");
       console.log(infoObj);
       return infoObj;
     },
     setInfo:function(value){
      //console.log("setInfo");
      //console.log(value);
      infoObj = value;
     }
     }

});
```

what I need to do to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on/36377476#36377476

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like the below code?

```
   mymedical.factory('dummyFactory', [function () {
        var infoObj = null;
        var myServiceFactory = {
            setObj: function (value) {
                infoObj = value;
            },
            getObj: function () {
                return infoObj;
            }
        };
        return myServiceFactory;
   }]);
```

in controller:

```
dummyFactory.setObj(null);
var val2 = dummyFactory.getObj();
```

**val2** will be null in console.

Comment: thanks for your answer! 
in the secound controller I want to get the data I did as you said var val2 = myService.getObj();
and in the first controller that set the value I did
$scope.viewCurrent = function(value){
  $scope.information = value;
  myService.setObj($scope.information);
}

and it still no working for me, it returns null

Comment: when you say var val2=myService.getObj(); is it means that you are using service not the factory? Also FYI your myService.setObj($scope.information); wont return anything..