# How to return some value from $scope.$on to $scope.$emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The commented part will lie under ***$scope.$on***. I need to return ***options*** to the place where I have kept ***$scope.$emit***. Please HELP!!!

```
if (gridConfig.Batch) {
                gridOption.dataSource.transport["parameterMap"] = function (options, operation) {
                    var data = {
                        options: options,
                        operation: operation
                    };
                    $scope.$emit('parameterMap', data);
                    //if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    //    angular.forEach(options.models, function (value) {
                    //        value.MfgDt = kendo.toString(value.MfgDt, "s");
                    //        value.ExpDt = kendo.toString(value.ExpDt, "s");
                    //        value.ProductType = value.ProductType.Id;
                    //    })
                    //    return options;
                    //}
                }
            }
```

Comment: Even if there is any other way to do this then let me know. Also this code is under angular custom directive which is being used in many places so I can't keep the commented code there. It has to be passed from somewhere outside.

Comment: Do you want to send data from $scope.$emit to $scope.$on ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye Yes.. I need that data

Comment: Okay take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-scope-on

Comment: I understood you wrong. I want to send data from $scope.$on to $scope.$emit...
@AmadouBeye

Comment: I already came across that post. But that was not helpful.

Comment: Someone please Help!!! I need to deliver this tomorrow morning

Comment: What exactly is the problem? are you able to transfer the data at all? and can you share your $scope.$on code?

Comment: This code is a part of angular directive which is made for handling all the grids in my project. If it's not a directive then the code will look this

Comment: `parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            angular.forEach(options.models, function (value) {
                                value.Mfg_Dt = kendo.toString(value.Mfg_Dt, "s");
                                value.Exp_Dt = kendo.toString(value.Exp_Dt, "s");
                                value.Product_Type = value.Product_Type.Id;
                            })
                            return options;
                        }
                    } `

Comment: My $scope.$on:
`$scope.$on('parameterMap',function(e, data){
            return function(){
                if (data.operation !== "read" && data.options.models) {
                    angular.forEach(data.options.models, function (value) {
                        value.Mfg_Dt = kendo.toString(value.Mfg_Dt, "s");
                        value.Exp_Dt = kendo.toString(value.Exp_Dt, "s");
                        value.Product_Type = value.Product_Type.Id;
                    })
                    return data.options;
                }
            }
            
        });`

Comment: I want to return that data.options to the place I kept my $scope.$emit
In case you have any other way then please let  me know @GalGrazia

Comment: @AlishaChaitali I think i know what you mean, i posted an answer, please tell me if that is what you wanted to achieve

Comment: @GalGrazia Exactly this is what I want

Comment: Thank you so much @GalGrazia .Worked like charm. I didn't knew we can use callbacks with emit and on

Comment: I already did that. But it's saying I need t have more than 15 reputation to accept your answer. Give me sometime.I ll increase my reputation and upvote your answer again

Comment: @GalGrazia I upvoted your answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AlishaChaitali i saw you got an answer already :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure i understand your question but if i do, you wanted a callback function from your **$scope.$on** to your **$scope.emit**.
If so, the code below will help you, please tell me if it's working because i haven't tested it.

```
if (gridConfig.Batch) {
            gridOption.dataSource.transport["parameterMap"] = function (options, operation) {
                var data = {
                    options: options,
                    operation: operation
                };
                $scope.$emit('parameterMap', data,function(returnedData){
                      //returnedData.options = the updated options
                });

            }
        }
```

**$scope.$on:**

```
$scope.$on('parameterMap', function (e, data,callback) {
    if (data.operation !== "read" && data.options.models) {
        angular.forEach(options.models, function (value) {
            value.MfgDt = kendo.toString(value.MfgDt, "s");
            value.ExpDt = kendo.toString(value.ExpDt, "s");
            value.ProductType = value.ProductType.Id;
        })
        callback(data);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it far simpler than the other answer, just adjust the data in the  directive, and use that as the return value.

```
if (gridConfig.Batch) {
            gridOption.dataSource.transport["parameterMap"] = function (options,   operation) {
                var data = {
                    options: options,
                    operation: operation
                };
                $scope.$emit('parameterMap', data);

                // by the time we reach here the directive 
                // will have altered the data object
                if (data.operation !== "read" && data.options.models) {
                    angular.forEach(options.models, function (value) {
                        value.MfgDt = kendo.toString(value.MfgDt, "s");
                        value.ExpDt = kendo.toString(value.ExpDt, "s");
                        value.ProductType = value.ProductType.Id;
                    })
                    return options;
                }
            }
        }
```

in the directive:

```
$scope.$on('parameterMap', function (e, data) {
   data.operation = "write" ; 
   data.options = {models: 'something here'} 
   // do something else here, whatever the purpose of the directive is
}
```