# Variable Function Names in Nested Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to implement nested directives. The inner directive is a button which calls a function in ng-click. The name of the function to be called is defined in the model.

To start off with, here is the plunker link. [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbIbwpeG2Wo1L99LV1LC?p=preview)

The problem is that the button does not know the function to be called.
Funnily enough, if I use a template for the outer directive using ng-include and variables rightly named in the scope, it works like a charm.

Some Code Snippets for you:

index.html:

```html
DIRECTIVES
<outer-directive functions="functions" datas="datas"></outer-directive>

<p>{{clicked}}</p>

NG-Include :
<div ng-include src="'outer-template.html'"></div>
```

Template for outer directive

```html
<div ng-repeat="d in datas">
  Hi, {{d}}
  <inner-directive 
    ng-repeat="funct in functions" 
    text="funct.text" 
    method="this[funct.method](d)">
  </inner-directive>
</div>
```

Controller

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.datas = [0, 1];
  $scope.functions = [{
    method: 'functOne',
    text: 'Funct One'
  }, {
    method: 'functTwo',
    text: 'Funct Two'
  }];


  $scope.clicked = 'Nothing happend';

  $scope.functOne = function(data) {
    $scope.clicked = data + ' pressed Funct 1';
  }

  $scope.functTwo = function(data) {
    $scope.clicked = data + ' pressed Funct 2';
  }

});
```

Outer Directive JS

```js
app.directive('outerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      functions: '=',
      datas: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'outer-template.html'
  }
});
```

Inner Directive JS

```js
app.directive('innerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      method: '&',
      text: '=',
      datas: '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="method(datas)"> {{text}}</button>'
  }
});
```

Comment: So, I decided to go with $emit and $on (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-scope-on))

Answer (score 0):

In call back function from directive to controller the parameters should be passed as an object.

Here is the demo plunker [click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RbFjFfqR1MDDa3Jwe8Gq?p=preview)

Hope it helps to understand how to pass param from directive to controller through call back function.

Now moving forward to nested directive :  The same process need to be followed to pass parameter across directive and hence finally to controller.

Let the controller be

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.datas = [0, 1];

  $scope.functions = [{
    "method": "functOne",
    "text": "Funct One"
  }, {
    "method": "functTwo",
    "text": "Funct Two"
  }];

  $scope.clicked = 'Nothing happend';

  $scope.functOne = function(id){
   $scope.clicked = id + ' .....pressed Funct 1';
  }

  $scope.functTwo = function(id){
    $scope.clicked = id + ' ....pressed Funct 2';
  }

});
```

Outer diretive

```
app.directive('outerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      outer: '&',
      datas: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'outer-template.html',
  }
});
```

Inner directive

```
app.directive('innerDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      inner: '&',
      text: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="clickMe()">click here</button>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.clickMe=function(){

          scope.inner({id:'hello... data is ' + scope.data });
        }
  }

  }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="func in functions">
      <outer-directive outer=$eval(func.method)(term) datas="datas"></outer-
       directive>
    </div>

    <p>{{clicked}}</p>

  </body>
```

Template

```
<div ng-repeat="d in datas">
<inner-directive inner="outer({term: id})" data="d"></inner-directive>
</div>
```

Here is the [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ydos7g9wSwzzXaOUcBFk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In my case, I need the functions to repeat within the outer directive, and not letting the outer directives repeat for each function. So I cannot bind each function with '&' in the outer directive.