# Angularjs: Data emitted in service not received by controller

Tags: angularjs

I want data received by the service to be transmitted to the controller but the controller does not receive the data.

Service:

```
angular.module('dataService', [])
    .constant('productCategoryUrl', ' /api/product/categories')
    .service('dataService', function ($rootScope, $http, $filter, $rootScope, productCategoryUrl) {

        var currentData = {};
        var productCategories = [];  

        return {
            setCurrentCategory: function (category, type) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('set-category', currentData);
            },
       }
   })
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('jordans')
    .controller('productCategoryCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, dataService) {
         $scope.productCategories = [];             

         $rootScope.$on('set-category', function (e, args) {                   
                $scope.currentData.category = args.category;
                $scope.currentData.type = args.type;

                console.log('*******productcategory.currentdata = ' 
                  + JSON.stringify($scope.currentData))                    
            });
  }
```

Comment: Are you making a call to `dataService.setCurrentCategory()`? i.e. does the event even get raised!?

Comment: Um, I prematurely accepted Ved's answer. It was not the solution.  To your question, seCurrentCategory() is called.

Answer (score 2):

Why two instances of `$rootScope`  added in service. Removing this should fix the issue

```
.service('dataService', function ($rootScope, $http, $filter, $rootScope, productCategoryUrl) {
```

Should be:

```
service('dataService', function ($http, $filter, $rootScope, productCategoryUrl) {
```

## Question:

> Why you are using $broadcast in service. You can directly create
>   method in service and call it from controller.

Also You need to destroy $rootScope listerner: See this answer:

[Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-scope-on/36377476#36377476)

Comment: Your implementation  need to be improved. Also You  need to destroy the rootscope listener.

Comment: Actually, Ved, I was a bit premature in accepting your answer. That was not the problem.

Comment: @koque so do you fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes, Ved, the problem was, at the time of the broadcast by the dataService, the productCategoryCtrl was not loaded so it wasn't receiving the broadcast.