# using $emit to pass a function from child to parent in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, emit

I want to send the result of a function to a parent controller from a child.

Here is my file structure

```
-submission.controller.js
--calculate.controller.js
```

In calculate.controller.js i have a function that looks like:

```
function validForm() {
  var checkForm = false;
  if(files === true) {
    checkForm = true;
  }
  return checkForm;
}
```

and i want to send the results of this function to the parent (submission.controller.js) and use it as an argument in a function.

```
showValidZip() {
  if (validForm() === true) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

So far i've tried to use $emit and $on to send validForm from calculate to submission but havent had much luck in doing so.

for example:

```
$scope.$emit('validForm', function () {
  var checkForm = false;
  if(files === true) {
    checkForm = true;
  }
  return checkForm;
});
```

and

```
$scope.showValidZip = function () {
  if ($scope.$on('validForm') === true) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

but it's not really working as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with $scope.$emit and $scope.$on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-scope-on)

Comment: File structure doesn't really matter. The way the controllers are used is. Please, explain what 'it's not really working as intended' exactly means and provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: You have to use `$rootscope` and also you have inverted `emit` and `on` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the controllers are used in such a way that they are parent-child of each other, you have two issues with the code you have provided:

1. `$scope.$emit` expects arguments next to event name so if you want to pass a function's result, you can have a seperate function and then call it from there like `$scope.$emit('validForm', myFunctionCall())`
2. Also, you can't use `$scope.$on` like that since it doesn't return anything. If you want to access the values sent from `$emit`, you can do that inside the listener function (second argument) i.e. something like this:

   ```
   $scope.$on('validForm', function(event, argument1) {
     // argument1 is the same as return value of myFunctionCall()
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

'Emit' from child.

```
$scope.$emit('validForm', function () {
var checkForm = false;
if(files === true) {
checkForm = true;
}
return checkForm;
});
```

Now Receive.

```
$scope.showValidZip = function () {
$scope.$on('validForm'), function(event, data) {
  if(data === true)
  return false;
});
return true;
};
```