# How to call other function after angular JS directive's reference function get called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<DirectiveName value1="someValue"  functionRef="someFunction()"></DirectiveName>
```

```
angular.module('Name', ['Dependencies']).
        directive('DirectiveName',
                function($timeout) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'AE',
                        replace: 'true',
                        template : 'HTML Template',
                        scope: {
                            variable1: '=value1',
                            Variable2: '&functionRef',
                        },
                        link: function(scope, watch){
                            
                        }
                    };
                });
```

1. I am using this angular JS custom directive, where we are passing reference of method from HTML to get called.
2. **Now we want to execute another function as well after execution of referenced function i.e. Variable2**

**We can not call common function from HTML or parent controller hence we need to call common function from angular directive it self after the execution of referenced function i.e. Variable2**

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you are still using angular 1. If that is true then check below link. Hope it will help you. If not then 'output' (eventEmitter) present in angular version > 2 

1.http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx
2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639275/using-emit-to-pass-a-function-from-child-to-parent-in-angularjs
```

Comment: Broadcasting is a different thing, anyway, I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('Name', ['Dependencies']).
        directive('DirectiveName',
                function($timeout) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'AE',
                        replace: 'true',
                        template : 'HTML Template',
                        scope: {
                            variable1: '=value1',
                            Variable2: '&functionRef',
                        },
                        link: function(scope, element, attr){
                            scope.Variable2 = function(){
                                
                                scope.$parent.$eval(attr.functionRef);
                                
                                /* other statement goes here */ 
                            }
                        }
                    };
                });
```

**Overriding function works, call referenced function from inside overridden function using $eval()**