# How to set default value of custom radio button in a modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, default-value

**Background:**

So I am working with a modal box for searching through a list of task entries within a database using a form to narrow results. In this modal box, there is a custom radio button that's used for selecting whether or not the task is in progress (simple "Yes" or "No" option). The goal is to set the "No" option as the default value whenever the modal is called. Currently, I am using `data-ng-init`; however, this only works the first time the modal is opened. If the user closes the modal and reopens it, the default value is no longer set. Below is a sample of what this custom button looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
      <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
      <button type="button" data-ng-init="tr.taskInProgress('No')" 
          title="Task In Progress: No" data-ng-click="tr.taskInProgress('No')"
          style="border:0;background:transparent">
      <img src="../images/selected.png" data-ng-switch-when="No" />
      <img src="../images/Deselect.png" data-ng-switch-when="Yes"  />
      <img data-ng-switch-when="" src="/nc/images/Deselect.png" /></button>
          <text>No
   </div>
   (another similar button, but for 'yes')
</div>
```

In the accompanying .js file, the following is used to help populate this modal:

```
/*--------- Get Tasks ---------*/
tr.closeGetTaskModal = closeGetTasModal;
tr.displayGetTaskMessage = true;
tr.selectedStatusType = getStatusType;
tr.trackingId = '';
tr.performGetTask = performGetTask;
tr.isTaskInProgess = isTaskInProgress;
```

And, in the same .js file, the following function is used to modify the radio:

```
function isTaskInProgress(newValue) {
    tr.isTaskInProgress = newValue;
}
```

I have been looking through others iterations on how they handle such cases, but I have been unlucky and have not found anything similar enough to what I am working with that works. I have tried setting the default in the `Get Tasks` section by modifying `isTaskInProgress('No')`, but this only locked the modal and I couldn't modify the option. I have tried setting the default inside the `isTaskInProgress` function; however, this only worked when the button was clicked, it failed to set a default. I tried seeing if `data-ng-default` would work; however, this didn't seem to be a recognized parameter. Does anyone have suggestions on how to modify this to get the desired results? Thank you all in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Small Disclaimer

I am taking the liberty of assuming you are using UI Bootstrap (since I see bootstrap classes in your sample HTML), so will be using Uib Modal in my example.

Bootstrap Modal docs: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

---

### Resolver / Callback Solution

You will most likely want to use the controller to set your **tr.isTaskInProgress** flag rather than using the **ng-init** directive (a bit more flexibility / readability).

Set **tr.isTaskInProgress** to *false* at the top of your target controller function, then pass its value to your modal as a property in a "Modal Resolve Object".

Bootstrap's explanation of the Resolve Object: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#ui-router-resolves

---

### Code

```
function MainController($scope, $uibModal) {
    let vm = this;
    vm.isTaskInProgress = false;

    // When you open the modal, pass in the isTaskProgress value
    let modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // Points to the script template
         controller: 'ModalController', // Points to the controller
         controllerAs: 'mc',
         windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
         backdrop: 'static',
         resolve: {
              isTaskInProgress: function() {
                   // pass the task state to the Modal
                   return vm.isTaskInProgress;
              }
         }
     });

  // handle the value(s) passed back from the modal
  modalInstance.result.then(returnedTaskState => {
    // reassign the returned value of the modal
    if (returnedTaskState !== null) {
      vm.isTaskInProgress = returnedTaskState;
    }
  });
}
```

---

### Working Example

https://plnkr.co/ryK7rG

In the interest of time, I've changed some of the variable / method names from what you have in your snippets. In the example, you can...

- Set the *In Progress* value before you open the modal and the modal reflects the In Progress value.
- Change the *In Progress* value inside the modal. On closing the modal, the value will be updated in the main page.

---

### SO Snippet

I realize the SO Snippet window is not exactly the best place for this example, but just tossing my example code in here in case Plunker is inconvenient for some reason.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  let app = angular
    .module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"])
    .controller("MainController", MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ["$scope", "$timeout", "$uibModal"];

  function MainController($scope, $timeout, $uibModal) {
    /**
     * John Papa Style Guide
     * https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md
     * */
    let vm = this;

    // ==== scoped variables ====
    vm.title = "AngularJS - Passing Toggled Values to a Modal"
    vm.taskInProgress = false;
    vm.taskButtonLocked = false;

    // ==== functions hoist ====
    vm.beginTask = _beginTask;

    function _beginTask() {
      vm.modalIsOpen = true;

      // do work

      openModal();
    }

    // ==== local functions ====
    function openModal() {
      // open the modal with configurations
      let modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', // Points to my script template
        controller: 'ModalController', // Points to my controller
        controllerAs: 'mc',
        windowClass: 'app-modal-window',
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
          taskInProgress: function() {
            // pass the task state to the Modal
            return vm.taskInProgress;
          }
        }
      });

      // handle the value(s) passed back from the modal
      modalInstance.result.then(returnedTaskState => {
        // reset control values after modal is closed
        vm.taskButtonLocked = false;
        vm.modalIsOpen = false;

        // reassign the returned value of the modal
        console.log("returnedTaskState: ", returnedTaskState);

        if (returnedTaskState !== null) {
          vm.taskInProgress = returnedTaskState;
        }
      });
    }
  }

})();

(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('ModalController', ModalController);

  ModalController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$uibModalInstance', 'taskInProgress'];

  function ModalController($scope, $timeout, $uibModalInstance, taskInProgress) {

    // Assign Cats to a Modal Controller variable
    let vm = this;
    
    vm.inProgress = taskInProgress;
    
    console.log("taskInProgress", taskInProgress)

    $scope.submit = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close(vm.inProgress);
    }

    $scope.close = function() {
      $uibModalInstance.close(null);
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
input[type="radio"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunk</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JQuery and Bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Stuff -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
  
   <!-- UI Bootstrap Stuff -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Our Angularjs App -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as tr">

  <!-- ==== MAIN APP HTML ==== -->
  <div class="container" style="padding:1em;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h2>{{ tr.title }}</h2>
          <h4><em><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362380/how-to-set-default-value-of-custom-radio-button-in-a-modal" target="_blank">SO Question #55362380</a></em></h4>
          <h4><em><a href="https://angularjs.org/" target="_blank">AngularJS - v1.7.8</a></em></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <h3>Task In Progress</h3>
            <div>
              <label>Yes:</label>
              <input type="radio"
                     ng-checked="tr.taskInProgress"
                     ng-click="tr.taskInProgress = true"
                     ng-disabled="tr.modalIsOpen">
            </div>
            <label>No:</label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   ng-checked="!tr.taskInProgress"
                   ng-click="tr.taskInProgress = false" 
                   ng-disabled="tr.modalIsOpen">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Open the modal:</label>
            <button type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-success" 
                    ng-click="tr.beginTask();" 
                    ng-disabled="tr.taskButtonLocked">
              <span>Begin Task</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- ==== MODAL HTML TEMPLATE ==== -->
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Task State:</label>
            <div style="padding:1em;background:rgba(200, 214, 229,0.3);">
              <p>
                <span ng-show="!mc.inProgress">
                  <span>Task is not in progress...&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                  <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                <span ng-show="mc.inProgress">
                  <span>Task is in progress...&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:1em;">
            <h3>Task In Progress</h3>
            <div>
              <label>Yes:</label>
              <input type="radio"
                     ng-checked="mc.inProgress"
                     ng-click="mc.inProgress = true">
            </div>
            <label>No:</label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   ng-checked="!mc.inProgress"
                   ng-click="mc.inProgress = false">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submit()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler, this has been very informative and helpful. Thank you again for taking the time to put this together.

Comment: @Brandon For sure! As an alternative to the Callback / Resolver method I suggested, you could also use an Event driven approach using $broadcast / $on / $emit. Both options should work well for your use case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-scope-on