# directives and inter-element communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created the following simple directive to redirect enter keypress events.

I think it might be a better to use emit a message to another directive, that handles the keypress event, rather than using a jQuery identifier, as I do here.

Consistent with Angular philosophy, what is best practice when dealing with element to element communication? why?

thanks

```
=========================================================
.directive('redirectEnter',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function($scope,$element,$attr) {
            $element.keypress(function($event) {
                if($event.keyCode == '13') {
                    $($attr.redirectEnter).click();
                    $event.stopPropagation();
                    $event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
=========================================================
<a redirect-enter="#apply">Redirect enter example</a>
<button id="apply">Apply</button> 
=========================================================
```

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another-in-angularjs . The idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML example doesn't have any logic wired to the button element via `ng-click`, etc., so for the sake of example, let's imagine a view like this:

```
<input ng-model="model.something">
<button ng-click="submit()">
```

(Remember, your DOM elements should be tied to logic via directives or a controller's scope. Using `$("#apply").click(...)` is a no-no!)

In this example, it's easy to say that we want the `input` element to eat "enter" keypresses and "redirect" them to the button. But what we *really* want an "enter" keypress in the `input` to do is *the action the button would otherwise perform*--in this case, calling the `submit` method on the scope.

Here is a directive that takes an expression to evaluate as its `redirect-enter` attribute (I'd probably call it `onEnter` or something) and evaluates the expression.

```
<input ng-model="model.something" redirect-enter="submit()">
<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Here is the directive that makes this work:

```
app.directive('redirectEnter', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function($scope,$element,$attr) {
      $element.keypress(function($event) {
        if($event.keyCode == '13') {
          $scope.$eval($attr.redirectEnter);
          $event.stopPropagation();
          $event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is an example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/HgD9y/

Note that, if you want the same behavior on a link element, you should use `ng-click`.

If you're struggling with keeping yourself from using plain jQuery selectors in your Angular code (like the no-no I mentioned at the top of this answer), consider this advice from the [Angular FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements, retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.
>
> If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled jQLite has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing Angular directives, especially binding to events.